# O que realmente é DDD e quando ele se aplica?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, ddd

Quando estudei MVC pela primeira vez no livro falava muito sobre DDD (Domain-Driven Design). Pelo que eu entendi na época, a ideia do DDD era simplesmente programar o software com foco no desenvolvimento da camada de domínio.

Depois disso, lendo sobre o processo de análise e projeto em orientação a objetos tive a impressão de que sempre que programamos um software orientado a objetos damos essa ênfase na camada de domínio, começando por ela e usando os requisitos pra montar ela corretamente.

Isso faz parecer que o DDD prega basicamente a mesma coisa que o processo de análise e projeto em orientação a objetos. Dessa forma, o que realmente é o DDD e quando ele se aplica de verdade? Quais as vantagens de se usar DDD em um projeto?

Eu sei que existe um livro chamado *Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software*, mas por ser um livro muito extenso nunca consegui parar pra ler ele. Existe alguma referência mais resumida sobre o assunto?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

*Domain-Driven Design* ou Projeto Orientado a Domínio é um padrão de modelagem de software orientado a objetos que procura reforçar conceitos e boas práticas relacionadas à OO.

Isso vem em contrapartida com o uso comum do *Data-Driven Design* ou Projeto Orientado a Dados, que a maioria dos desenvolvedores usa sem mesmo ter consciência disso.

## Data-Driven Development

Já ouvi várias vezes que os dados são a coisa mais importante em uma empresa, logo a modelagem deve sempre começar pensando no banco de dados.

Não é nada incomum desenvolvedores .Net, Java e C++ começarem um sistema estabelecendo os **tipos** que eles vão usar e o relacionamento entre eles. Esses tipos geralmente são objetos "burros", com *getters* e *setters*, representando nada mais, nada menos, que uma tabela do banco de dados.

O problema com essa abordagem é que ela não faz bom uso dos recursos da Orientação a Objetos. Muitos acham que *getters* e *setters* são o auge do encapsulamento, mas na prática esses métodos permitem ao usuário recuperar e alterar todos os atributos. Não há ganho algum, a não ser muito código desnecessário.

Enfim, muita gente acha que está usando OO, mas as classes poderiam ser facilmente substituídas por registros ou estruturas, de acordo com a linguagem utilizada.

## Domain-Driven Development

A ideia inicial do DDD é voltar à uma modelagem OO mais pura, por assim dizer. Devemos esquecer de como os dados são persistidos e nos preocupar em como representar melhor as necessidades de negócio em classes e comportamentos (métodos).

Isso significa que em DDD um `Cliente` pode não ter um *setter* para os seus atributos comuns, mas pode ter métodos com lógica de negócio que neste domínio de negócio pertencem ao cliente, como `void associarNovoCartao(Cartao)` ou `Conta recuperarInformacoesConta()`.

Em resumo, as classes modeladas e os seus métodos deveriam representar o negócio da empresa, usando inclusive a mesma nomenclatura. A persistência dos dados é colocada em segundo plano, sendo apenas uma camada complementar.

## Quando não usar DDD

### Às vezes só é necessário um CRUD

DDD não é uma solução para tudo. A maioria dos sistemas possui uma boa parte composta por cadastros básicos (CRUD) e não seria adequado usar DDD para isso.

O DDD deve ajudar na modelagem das classes mais importantes e mais centrais do sistema de forma e diminuir a complexidade e ajudar na manutenção das mesmas, afinal este é o objetivo dos princípios de orientação a objetos.

### Compartilhando dados com outros sistemas

Rotinas de integração que recebem ou disponibilizam dados para outros sistemas não devem ser "inteligentes".

Muitos desenvolvedores acabam modelando suas classes de negócios tentando resolver as questões internas do sistema e, ao mesmo tempo, pensando em como essas classes serão expostas para outros sistemas.

Padrões como DTO (*Data Transfer Object*) que usam objetos "burros" são mais adequados para isso.

## Considerações finais

O DDD não tenta resolver todos os problemas de todas as camadas de um sistema.

Seu foco é na modelagem das entidades principais de negócio usando a linguagem adequada daquele domínio para facilitar a manutenção, extensão e entendimento.

Particularmente, eu não seguiria à risca o padrão, até porque existem inúmeros padrões e variações de modelagem OO. Estude os princípios por detrás desses padrões, pois eles são geralmente parecidos e veja o que funciona melhor para cada projeto.

## Referências

1. [DDD – Introdução a Domain Driven Design](http://www.agileandart.com/2010/07/16/ddd-introducao-a-domain-driven-design/)
2. [Coding for Domain-Driven Design: Tips for Data-Focused Devs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342868.aspx)
3. [*Domain Driven Design Quickly*](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) (e-book gratuito)

---

<sup>Nota: escrevi termos como *domain-driven* com hífen, pois quando duas ou mais palavras formam um adjetivo composto no Inglês elas geralmente devem ser "ligadas".No caso, *domain-driven* é um adjetivo de *design*. ([Referência](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm))</sup>

Comment: "Muitos acham que getters e setters são o auge do encapsulamento, mas na prática..." Eu sempre odiei getters e setters, mas não sabia muito bem por que. Com essa explicação, tudo faz sentido agora! Imagino que esse deve ser um dos recursos mais mal utilizados da OO...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Às vezes o programador tem medo de simplesmente expôr um dado de uma estrutura de dados, então ele escreve `getters` e `setters`. Há quem diga que um objeto sequer expõe dados, mas apenas comportamentos (que seriam justamente os `getters` e `setters`): http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html. Este aí não deve gostar de linguagens como C#, onde `getters` e `setters` são transparentes ao consumidor do objeto e se apresentam como simples dados expostos (exceto por um ícone diferenciado na IDE).

Comment: "pode ter métodos com lógica de negócio que neste domínio de negócio pertencem ao cliente", o que significa domínio nesse contexto? Pode me dar um sinônimo disso?

Comment: @HeyJoe Domínio é o que costumamos chamar os conceitos adotados por uma determinada área de negócios. Quando criamos um modelo de dados para um sistema, geralmente nos baseamos no domínio que aquele sistema pertence. Por exemplo, num sistema de um banco, o cliente fica associado a uma conta e esta a um cartão de crédito, mas numa loja virtual o cartão fica associado diretamente ao cliente. São domínios diferentes com regras diferentes.

Answer (score 67):

## O que é DDD?

**Domain-Driven Design** (DDD) é uma abordagem de desenvolvimento de software em que o design é orientado pelo domínio, ou seja, pela área de conhecimento à qual o software se aplica.

Outra forma de dizer é: em DDD, o design da solução é orientado pelas regras de negócio.

Não significa que outros aspectos do software como persistência ou modelagem de dados sejam ignorados. Muito pelo contrário - o DDD apresenta soluções que têm em conta todas as camadas do sistema.

## Por que DDD?

O principal objetivo do DDD é manter sob controle a complexidade inerente aos softwares que atendem necessidades complexas.

Ele parte da premissa de que o desenvolvimento de software é uma luta constante contra a complexidade. Quando não controlada ativamente, a complexidade aumenta o custo de desenvolvimento, de evolução e de manutenção, corrói a qualidade, degrada a performance, abre brechas para que gurus ou heróis se estabeleçam.

## Como se faz DDD?

O objetivo é perseguido aplicando-se um conjunto de conceitos, *design patterns*, e até comportamentos (das pessoas) no desenvolvimento do software. Veja alguns (repito, **alguns**) exemplos:

#### a) Conceitos

- **Model:** Descrição de alguns aspectos do domínio. Na prática, é a modelagem dos objetos de negócio.
- **Bounded Context:** Um único *model* não precisa resolver todos os problemas de um sistema complexo. Um sistema pode ter múltiplos *models* e os limites de um *model* devem estar bem definidos. Cada *model* evolui sem distrair-se com os demais.
- **Ubiquitous Language:** Uma linguagem comum, capaz de descrever o *domain*, o *model*, o contexto, e que deve ser praticada por todos - desenvolvedores, especialistas em negócio, e pelo próprio código. Ou seja, **o código fala a linguagem do negócio**. Uma mudança em um termo de negócio implicará na mudança do código. É difícil eleger o conceito mais importante do DDD, mas se eu tivesse de fazê-lo, escolheria a *Ubiquitous Language*.

#### b) Design patterns

- **Entities:** Objetos que possuem identidade e que são distinguidos por esta identidade e não apenas por suas características. Obviamente, estamos falando de identitidade para o negócio. Além de atributos, *Entities* também podem ter comportamentos.
- **Aggregates:** Conjunto de *entities* agregadas por uma *entity* raiz. Algumas *entities* não possuem por si só um significado global no domínio; ao invés, elas só fazem sentido quando precedidas por uma *entity* "pai". Esta *entity* pai é então a raiz de um *aggregate* e as *entities* filhas só podem ser acessadas através desta *entity* pai.
- **Services:** Operações de negócio que não são responsabilidade de nenhuma *entity* em particular.

Infelizmente, é comum estes e outros *design patterns* do DDD serem confundidos com outros puramente técnicos por conta dos nomes semelhantes.

#### c) Comportamentos

- **Continuous integration:** Desenvolvido por um time, o *model* pode acabar evoluindo em direções opostas, ser fragmentado ou quebrado. É necessário integrar o código continuamente, com execução de testes automatizados.
- **Hands-on Modelers:** Quem modela também sabe codificar e de fato o faz, ainda que menos que outras pessoas no time (exceção ao especialista de negócio, que ajuda a modelar mas não programa). Além disso, todos que programam entendem o *model*, participam de discussões sobre ele e estão em contato constante com o especialista de negócio.
- **Refactoring:** Não apenas para resolver aspectos técnicos do código sem afetar comportamento, mas também para aprimorar o próprio *model*.

## Quando se utiliza DDD?

Eu descrevi aqui alguns poucos aspectos do DDD pois não se pode ensinar a fazê-lo com pouco texto e só se pode aprendê-lo com muita prática. DDD é complexo, difícil, a curva de aprendizagem é longa.

Então, DDD é um desperdício em domínios triviais ou mais orientados a dados do que a regras de negócio complexas.

Os projetos que melhor se beneficiam de DDD são os de regras de negócio bastante complexas. Além disso, é necessário ter condições propícias como capacidade de desenvolvimento iterativo e um especialista de negócio disponível para o time de desenvolvimento.

## Quais são as vantagens de se utilizar DDD?

As vantagens advém do alcance do objetivo do DDD. O suprasumo de um software desenvolvido usando DDD é você delegar a correção de um bug ou mesmo o desenvolvimento de um recurso novo a uma pessoa nova no time depois de ter conversado com ela usando apenas lápis e papel, sem nem ligar o computador - ou seja, não se conversa sobre o código, conversa-se sim a respeito do negócio.

## Considerações sobre DDD e Orientação a Objetos

> "Isso faz parecer que o DDD prega basicamente a mesma coisa que o processo de análise e projeto em orientação a objetos."

Nesta resposta espero ter deixado claro que o DDD é **diferente** de orientação a objetos, pois DDD entrega conceitos e *design patterns* que você não precisa utilizar para fazer um código perfeitamente orientado a objetos.

## Existe alguma referência mais resumida sobre o assunto?

Não conheço nenhuma boa referência resumida. Todos os resumos que encontro possuem vários equívocos. Existem boas discussões apenas sobre tópicos específicos.

O próprio Eric Evans (autor do [livro que é a certidão de nascimento do DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)), publicou um [resumo](http://domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DDD_Reference_2015-03.pdf) do seu livro, mas não é tão resumido assim (62 páginas) e a meu ver serve como referência apenas para quem já leu o livro ou já conhece DDD por experiência.

Não quero dizer que você precisa primeiro ler e assimilar todo o livro antes de tentar DDD. A prática pode sim vir antes do conhecimento profundo. Muitos desenvolvedores pensam estar fazendo DDD depois de lerem uma breve lista dos seus *design patterns* - é um bom começo, mas quem pára por aí nunca chega a conhecer os reais benefícios do DDD.

## Conclusão

Para esta resposta não cabe uma conclusão menor do que o próprio texto :-)

Comment: Duas partes que não entendi bem: a explicação de _Aggregates_ e a explicação de por que DDD vai além da orientação a objetos. Como uma coisa vai além de outra entregando conceitos que você não precisa utilizar para implementá-la? O que significa isso?

Comment: Relendo agora acho que entendi os Aggregates. É a mesma noção do UML, correto? De agregação vs. composição que foi perguntado [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25619/composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-e-como-usar).

Comment: @Piovezan Em DDD, *aggregates* tem um significado mais próprio. Tentei melhorar a descrição trocando uma de suas características (identidade não global) por uma analogia (*entity pai/raiz* -> *entity filha sem significado quando isolada da entidade pai*). Um exemplo poderia ser `Pessoa -> Telefones {residencial, celular, comercial, contato}`. Meu telefone residencial não faz sentido se não for precedido da minha identificação. Quanto a DDD x OOP, simplifiquei a resposta (uma não estende a outra como ficou parecendo, apenas são coisas distintas). Obrigado por contribuir e pode mandar mais :-)

Comment: Penso que para quem pensa em aprender/aplicar DDD pode começar aplicando alguns dos princípios, tornando assim viável sua implementação em pequenos projetos.

Answer (score 17):

O que eu li a respeito e também participando de um projeto foi:

O objetivo principal é orientar o seu projeto para o negócio, ou seja, seu código tem que falar exatamente como o negócio está aplicado na sua empresa.

Por exemplo sua empresa tem a área Financeiro, logo seu código deveria ter uma *class* chamada `Financeiro` e como métodos `Emitir()`, `Faturar()` etc. É claro, DDD é muito mais do que isso. Sei também que no começo é difícil aplicá-lo devido aos acoplamentos e até mesmo entendimento do negócio.

Um link em português que pode ajudar a entender melhor seria: http://www.agileandart.com/2010/07/16/ddd-introducao-a-domain-driven-design/

Answer (score 12):

Um dos grandes problemas de adotar o DDD, do meu ponto de vista, é que é necessário um sólido conhecimento da tecnologia de linguagem que você usa:

quando pegamos pra estudar o DDD, os autores especialistas até tentam dar uma forma de ensinar voltada à linguagem que eles usam.

Um bom exemplo que eu posso te dar, com minha experiência com DDD e .NET é que,
para que você possa criar um software usando DDD, você precisa ter bastante perseverança em estudar muitos padrões de projetos da linguagem, de forma conjunta, o que dificulta pois a maioria dos tutoriais e livros que encontramos pela internet e até mesmo cursos, explicam tudo de forma separada.

Você para construir um software usando o padrão DDD, claro, existe algumas coisas básicas que você deve fazer para que seja verdadeiramente um DDD, mas, um software sólido e muito bem construído pelo menos na plataforma .net que eu posso te dizer usa no mínimo:

DDD, TDD(Test Driven Development) para cada camada, BDD(Behavior Driven Development), Injeção de Dependência, EntityFramework(pode ser outros), code-first, structureMapper, specifications, DomainEvent, Validation, Factories...

enfim existe uma série de padrões de projeto, e frameworks que devemos ter sólidos conhecimentos...  e não simplesmente entender o DDD apenas pelo livro...

e ter uma forte lógica de programação para que possamos tirar o máximo de proveito da tecnologia que a linguagem que escolhemos possa oferecer...