# Composição e agregação: quais as diferenças e como usar?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Em orientação a objetos é comum que objetos de uma certa classe possuam referências a um ou mais objetos de outras classes. Um exemplo muito simples é um objeto de uma classe `Pedido` que possui referência a uma lista de `Itens`, de forma que cada objeto desse tipo possua referência a vários objetos de outro tipo.

Acontece que em alguns casos chamam isso de composição e em outros casos chamam isso de agregação. Pesquisando li que composição é quando um dos objetos não existe independente do outro e agregação é quando os dois podem existir independentemente. É só isso mesmo?

Mesmo se for só isso, eu ainda não consigo identificar quais as implicações disso na prática. Basicamente, nos dois casos basta ter uma propriedade no objeto cujo tipo é a classe do outro tipo. Não tem em código uma diferença entre agregação e composição, então quais as utilidades de diferenciar esses dois casos e qual a diferença dessas duas abordagens na prática?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A diferença entre composição e agregação tem relação com a existência dos objetos. Essa diferença não é tratada pelas linguagens de programação que seguem o paradigma orientado a objetos (pelo menos não as convencionais: java, c#, c++).

Toda vez que temos composição, significa que *a parte não existe sem o todo*.

Toda vez que temos agregação, significa que *a parte pode ser compartilhada entre vários objetos*.

### Orientação a objetos ou UML?

O comportamento de agregação não pertence exclusivamente ao paradigma orientado a objetos. Temos o mesmo comportamento no paradigma imperativo. É o caso das estruturas em C. Veja um exemplo:

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
    char *name;
    enum { male, female } sex;
};
```

*age, name e sex compõem o tipo Person*

```
struct bintree
{
    struct bintree *left, *right;
    // some data
};
```

*bintree é composta de left e right, que são bintree*. Composição reflexiva.

Veja o conceito de composição descrito em várias [linguagens que não são orientadas a objetos na wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Composite_types_in_C).

### Tipos de associação em UML

Quando falamos de *agregação* e *composição* estamos falando de casos especiais de tipos de associação entre classes. Existem, em UML, associações: simples, agregação, generalização, dependência, realização (e devem existir outras que não me recordo agora).

O tipo de associação **agregação** pode ser classificada basicamente de duas formas: agregação de composição e agregação compartilhada (ou reflexiva).

#### Agregações

Esses tipos de relações são chamados assim porque agregam valor para o objeto relacionado. Esse é um tipo especializado de associação que nos permite encarar a relação entre os objetos como: Todo/Parte.

Todo/Parte significa que um dos lados da associação (um classe) é chamado de **Todo** e o outro lado é chamado de **Parte**, já que a parte nos permite pensar que: A **Parte** está contida no **Todo**.

#### Composição (ou agregação de composição)

Toda vez que dizemos que a relação entre duas classe é de **composição** estamos dizendo que uma dessas classe (a Parte) está contida na outra (o Todo) e a parte não vive/não existe sem o todo.

Sendo assim, toda vez que destruirmos o todo, a parte que é única e exclusiva do todo se vai junto. Por esse motivo que algum dizem que: a parte *está contida* no todo. Quando se joga o todo fora, a parte estava dentro e se vai junto.

#### Agregação (ou agregação compartilhada)

Essa também é uma relação todo/parte, porém, nesse caso dizemos que a parte é compartilhada por outros (por isso agregação compartilhada). Isso significa que a parte de um tipo `A` está contida em um tipo `B`, quando esse tem relação de agregação entre eles, porém, essa mesma parte `A` não existe somente para **compor** `B`, essa parte pode agregar outros tipos.

#### Resumindo

Estabelecemos o que são agregações de composição e compartilhada, agora que os nomes fazem sentido podemos exemplificar da seguinte forma:

- Composição (Agregação de composição)

> É necessário que exista pelo menos um item em uma nota fiscal para que a nota fiscal exista.

*Logo*: NotaFiscal é composta de ItemNotaFiscal.

- Agregação (agregação compartilhada)

> Se eu tiver um sistema de cadastro de times, preciso cadastras várias pessoas para agregar os times, assim, cada pessoa pode agregar um time, nenhum time, ou vários times. A pessoa é independente do time, mas agrega valor a ele.

*Logo*: Time é agregado por Pessoa.

**Não há diferença na implementação e sim no comportamento**

Em ambos os tipo de relação não há diferença no momento da implementação, veja um exemplo em C#:

**Composição**

```
class NotaFiscal: IDisposable {
    IList<ItemNotaFiscal> Itens {get;set;}
}

class ItemNotaFiscal: IDisposable { ... }
```

**Agregação**

```
class Time {
    IList<Pessoa> Integrantes {get;set;}
}

class Pessoa {}
```

Porém, os comportamentos **semânticos** das associações devem estar presentes quanto a existência. Para composição, por exemplo, poderíamos forçar que toda vez que uma nota seja criada, uma nova lista de ItemNotaFiscal deve ser criado. E toda vez que a nota fiscal for apagada, os itens devem ser destruídos.

```
class NotaFiscal {
    IList<ItemNotaFiscal> Itens {get;set;}
    NotaFiscal(){
        // Cria lista nova
        Itens = new List<ItemNotaFiscal>();
    }
    
    void Dispose() {
        foreach(var item in Itens){
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, os itens serão destruídos junto com a nota fiscal.

Para agregação não seria necessário esses tratamento de criação e destruição de objetos. Já que as partes podem ser compartilhadas.

**Agregações e multiplicidade são diferentes**

Muitos acham que *toda vez que existir um agregação/composição teremos uma lista/array das partes*, porém, o que nos diz se teremos mais de um tipo associado é a **multiplicidade** e não o tipo de associação. Independente do tipo de associação, a multiplicidade pode ser: 0,1,* ou n..m. Então, toda vez que uma associação for 1 para 1, não temos listas em nenhum dos lados.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: Composição não é multiplicidade]

```
class Carro
{
    Motor UnicoEExclusivoMotor {get;set;}
}

class Motor{}
```

Nesse caso, o `Motor` é único e exclusivo para o `Carro`, e toda vez que o `Carro` for destruído, o `Motor` será destruído também.

Esse engano ocorre porque na maioria das vezes em que um objetos está relacionado a uma coleção de outros objetos, essa associação expressa um dos tipos de agregação. Associações de agregação onde não ocorrem coleções são incomuns por conta disso.

### Conclusão

Agregação ou composição são tipo de relação entre dois objetos/tipos. Cada um dos tipos de associação está relacionado ao comportamento entre os objetos e com a existência desses de acordo com o conceito todo/parte.

Agregações não tem nada haver com multiplicidade. Embora, na maioria das vezes, objetos associados a uma coleção de outros objetos expressem, em suas relações, um comportamento de agregação.

Comment: Aproveitei para escrever um artigo sobre o assunto em https://www.anmaia.com.br/posts/composicao-e-agregacao-tem-diferenca

Answer (score 31):

### A diferença é apenas conceitual.

#### Agregação

É quando um objeto possui outros objetos, ele não depende desses objetos para existir.

Exemplo:

[image: agregacao]

Uma Gaveta pode conter Meias, mas a Gaveta não é feita de Meias. Ou seja, mesmo sem Meias a Gaveta ainda existirá.

#### Composição

É quando um objeto é formado por outros objetos. Ou seja, suas partes o compõem, sem elas o objeto não existe.

Exemplo:

[image: composicao]

Um Computador é formado por seus componentes, como por exemplo placa-mãe, gabinete, hd, memória, placa de vídeo, etc. Sem todas essas peças não existe nosso Computador de acordo com a representação do diagrama. Logo, no nosso diagrama o Computador é um conceito, pois concretamente ele é composto por um conjunto diferentes componentes.

#### O que muda então?

Como eu disse no começo, a diferença é apenas conceitual. Quem bater o olho no seu diagrama de classes entenderá com facilidade o que seu sistema está modelando, e essa é a intenção dos diagramas UML, uma representação visual do seu sistema. Já no momento da implementação, tanto o código da agregação quanto o da composição podem muito bem serem escritos da mesma forma.

Comment: Simples e direto!

Answer (score 11):

De fato, não há implicações práticas imediatamente visíveis de se tratar composição e agregação como uma coisa só. Pessoalmente, nunca me importei com essa distinção. Entretanto, saber se determinada propriedade pode ou não existir como uma entidade independente pode ter impacto na forma como você modela seu sistema, de modo que é importante você ter - ainda que só na sua mente - essa distinção.

Considere o caso da composição. No seu exemplo, todo item pertence a um pedido, e não existe fora do contexto de um pedido. *Talvez* fosse possível mover um item de um pedido a outro, mas na prática isso não faz muito sentido. Dessa forma, temos algumas implicações:

- Uma classe `Item` pode ter uma referência para o seu `Pedido`. Se tiver, essa referência não aceitaria valores nulos;
- O construtor de `Item` deveria receber um parâmetro obrigatório especificando qual o `Pedido` a que pertence (seja pra atribuir a propriedade mencionada acima, seja para outros propósitos). Não faz sentido criar um objeto de `Item` sem saber qual é o objeto `Pedido` correspondente;
- A classe `Pedido` pode ter métodos para listar seus itens, reordená-los, acrescentar ou remover itens, etc, mas isso deve ser feito de forma consistente com as regras da composição:

  - Se o construtor de `Item` é público, criar o item deve automaticamente adicioná-lo ao pedido. Nesse caso, a classe `Pedido` não teria métodos para "adicionar" - uma vez que isso é feito simplesmente instanciando a classe `Item`;
  - Caso contrário, o `Pedido` é o único que poderia criar itens - agindo como uma **fábrica** para os mesmos.
  - Ao se remover um item de um pedido, o mesmo deve ser excluído completamente (ou marcado como tal, se tornando inutilizável).
- Por fim, ao implementar a persistência desses objetos, é importante garantir que os itens não existam sem pedidos (ex.: num banco de dados, a chave estrangeira de `item` pra `pedido` seria "não-*nullable*").

Já no caso da agregação, a API seria diferente. Se tivermos por exemplo uma classe `Funcionario` que por sua vez pertence a um `Departamento`. A princípio, poderíamos ter funcionários sem departamento fixo, ou talvez funcionários movendo-se de um departamento para outro. Nesse caso, as implicações seriam as seguintes:

- Uma classe `Funcionario` pode ter uma referência para o seu `Departamento`. Se tiver, essa referência deve aceitar valores nulos;
- A classe `Funcionario` deve ter ao menos um construtor sem parâmetro para `Departamento`. E os construtores que recebem esse parâmetro devem aceitar um valor nulo. Pois nesse caso faz sim sentido criar um objeto de `Funcionario` sem um objeto `Departamento` correspondente;
- A classe `Departamento` pode ter métodos para listar, acrescentar, remover, etc, mas isso deve ser feito de forma consistente com a agregação:

  - Os métodos para adicionar devem receber objetos `Funcionario` pontos; esses métodos seriam então responsáveis por atribuir o funcionário ao departamento e, se necessário, removendo-o do seu departamento anterior caso exista (ou recusando sua inserção, conforme o caso);
  - Os métodos para remover deveriam então colocar o funcionário num estado "sem departamento", mas deixando ele "vivo" (i.e. sem excluir o objeto, tornando possível que ela seja usado e/ou reinserido num departamento diferente).
  - Ao implementar a persistência desses objetos, deve-se permitir funcionários sem departamento (ex.: num banco de dados, a chave estrangeira de `funcionario` pra `departamento` seria *nullable*).

Ou seja, no fim das contas saber se você está lidando com um caso de agregação ou composição acaba por ter impacto na sua modelagem de dados e na sua API. Nas classes em si, a diferença maior está não nos seus atributos mas nas suas **operações** - uma vez que é importante criá-las de acordo com o que é válido segundo a sua lógica. Seria possível, a princípio, criar um código "frankenstein" - misturando composição com agregação - e o compilador não iria te impedir, mas isso não quer dizer que esse seria um design bom e válido.

Answer (score 0):

Tentando ser bem sucinto:

Na agregação, um objeto A é referenciado, ou "chamado" dentro de outro objeto B. Ou seja, você cria dois objetos A e B e um atributo de B é o objeto A (um é parte do outro). Mas para isso acontecer, os dois tem que existir, independentes entre si. Por essa independência (coexistência), dizem que "a parte pode viver sem o todo". O que isso quer dizer? Eu disse que um faz parte do outro, certo? Então A é a parte. E B é o todo. Como os dois já existiam num primeiro momento, eles não tem dependência entre si.

Já na composição, uma classe é instanciada, gerando o objeto A, no momento da definição de um atributo de um outro objeto B. Ou seja, o objeto A é criado durante a definição de um atributo de B. Logo, A, que é parte, só existirá se B existir. Portanto, podemos dizer que "a parte não existe sem o todo".

Agora, como isso se aplica na prática?

Exemplo de Agregação: Digamos que eu crie a classe Dono e a classe Gato. Agora eu crio um objeto gato e um objeto dono. Os dois existem. Dono tem um método adotar(pet), em que ele adota um gato. A função cria um atributo para Dono que recebe um gato. Se eu colocar como argumento de dono.adotar(pet) o objeto gato que foi criado, Dono agora passa a ter o gato como um dos seus atributos. E esse é exatamente o mesmo gato que foi criado. Mas se dono deixar de existir, o gato continua existindo normalmente, porque ele já existia antes.

Exemplo de Composição: Agora digamos que eu crie a classe Pessoa e a classe Endereço. Eu crio o objeto pessoa. Concorda comigo que não faz muito sentido eu criar um objeto endereço, se ele não está associado a ninguém? Se eu fosse criar um objeto endereço e ele fosse atribuído a pessoa, seria dela e apenas dela (com exceção de quem morasse com ela). Então faria mais sentido eu criar um atributo endereço dentro da classe Pessoa, que vai receber parâmetros relativos a informações específicas do endereço de cada objeto pessoa que for criado. Se o objeto pessoa for deletado, não faz sentido existir um objeto endereço. E como ele foi definido dentro de pessoa, ele vai ser deletado da mesma forma.