# O que é associação simples em orientação a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Quando perguntei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25619/composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-e-como-usar) sobre composição e agregação eu estava achando que qualquer associação entre dois objetos se enquadrava nessas categorias (sem contar com herança). Mas aí na resposta vi que existe a chamada *associação simples*. Pesquisei na internet sobre isso e a maior parte do que achei era em relação a como representar isso em diagramas UML inves de propriamente o que esse tipo de associação representa.

Olhando no wikipedia vi o seguinte

> **Associação:** é o mecanismo pelo qual um objeto utiliza os recursos de outro. Pode tratar-se de uma *associação simples* "usa um" ou de um acoplamento "parte de". Por exemplo: Um humano usa um telefone. A tecla "1" é parte de um telefone

Dessa forma, invés de ser uma relação de parte/todo como nas relações de agregação e composição uma associação simples é uma relação de uso? Eu achei que relações de uso fossem representadas por agregações, já que nesses tipos de associações a parte existe independente do todo, então fiquei confuso.

Assim o que realmente é a associação simples e como ela difere das outras formas de associação em orientação a objetos?

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade, **todas as relações são associações**, o que vai diferenciar uma da outra é a participação dos objetos no contexto da aplicação.

**Por exemplo:**

O fato do objeto roda, estar disponível em uma loja, caracteriza uma associação simples, uma loja poderia ter N rodas, vender estas rodas, e a loja continua existindo, aguardando receber mais rodas no estoque.

Se este objeto roda estiver no carro, é uma agregação, o carro possui rodas para funcionar, e não existe carro que funcione sem rodas, por enquanto.

Se a roda estiver em um carrinho de compras com outros produtos, é uma composição, o carrinho existe em função destes produtos, que podem ser de 1 a N objetos, carrinho depende dos objetos para existir, esta é a finalidade dele, carregar objetos.

**Explicação:**

Se um objeto *pode ser uma coisa* em determinado contexto, então o contexto é uma Associação simples.

Se um objeto *tem uma coisa*, seja ela um objeto ou não, então o contexto é uma Agregação.

Se um objeto *é uma coisa ou parte de uma coisa*, então o contexto é uma Composição.

Orientação a objetos é um paradigma de programação onde N objetos colaboram com suas funcionalidades para que tenhamos uma aplicação, os objetos compõem a orientação a objetos, de forma que, se você tiver apenas 1 objeto, você não tem uma aplicação orientada a objetos. Os objetos precisam se relacionar uns com os outros. Esse relacionamento dos objetos, chama-se associação. Algumas associações são mais fortes, outras mais fracas.
Para saber que tipo de relaçao cada um é, ou deverá ser, precisamos identificar a funcionalidade de cada objeto em cada relação.

Comment: boa resposta +1