# Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Sobre relacionamentos entre classes, qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição?

Comment: Relacionado: ["Composição e agregação: quais as diferenças e como usar?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25619/215)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As definições são conceituais. Na prática o importante é que temos associações genéricas entre objetos e o termo mais usado costuma ser composição, mesmo quando de fato não seja uma, formalmente falando. Alguns pequenos detalhes farão ser uma coisa ou outra. O que importa é tentar manter o [acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) o mais baixo possível. Neste aspecto a associação simples é a mais indicada... quando viável.

Curiosamente os termos são usados para estruturar dados mas são os algoritmos que definirão a real diferença.

- A [**associação**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming)) entre dois objetos ocorre quando eles são completamente independentes entre si mas eventualmente estão relacionados. Ela pode ser considerada uma relação de muitos para muitos. Não há propriedade (*ownership*) nem dependência entre eles. A relação é eventual.

Um exemplo é a relação entre um professor e alunos. Um aluno pode ter vários professores e um professor pode ter vários alunos. Um não depende do outro para existir. Professores podem existir sem alunos e e alunos podem existir sem professores (pelo menos em requisitos normais). Outro exemplo:

```
class Cliente {
    var contatos = new List<Contato>();
    AdicionarContato(Contato contato) {
        contatos.Add(contato); //este contato independe deste cliente
    }
}
```

[image: Associação]

- A [**agregação**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) não deixa de ser uma associação mas existe uma exclusividade e determinados objetos só podem se relacionar a um objeto específico. É uma relação de um para muitos. Um objeto é proprietário de outros mas não há dependência, então ambos podem existir mesmo que a relação não se estabeleça. Na verdade há controvérsias sobre a exata definição e o que é mais importante, a relação de um para muitos ou a propriedade.

Um exemplo é a relação entre os professores e os departamentos. Departamentos podem ter vários professores. E o professor só pode estar vinculado a um único departamento. Mas eles são independentes. Um professor pode existir sem vínculo com um departamento e este não depende de professores para existir. Outro exemplo:

```
class Cliente {
    var notas = new List<NotaFiscal>();
    EmitirNota(NotaFiscal nota) {
        notas.Add(nota); //a nota existe sempre mesmo que o cliente não exista mais
    }
}
```

[image: Agregação]

- A [**composição**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) é uma agregação que possui dependência entre os objetos, ou seja, se o objeto principal for destruído, os objetos que o compõe não podem existir mais. Há a chamada *relação de morte*.

Um exemplo é a relação entre uma a universidade e os departamentos. Além da universidade possuir vários departamentos, eles só podem existir se a universidade existir. Há uma dependência. Outro exemplo:

```
class NotaFiscal {
    var itens = new List<item>();
    AdicionarItem(Produto produto, int quantidade) {
        itens.Add(new Item(produto, quantidade); //este item só existe nesta nota
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Agreggationn.cs).

[image: Composição]

Os termos possuem esta relação:

[image: Relação]

Descobri depois que já há uma [pergunta que responde em detalhes sobre os tipos específicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25619/101) que são mais importantes. Não chega ser exata duplicata.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

sumarizando:

em associação não temos dono. os obJectos têm tempo de vida próprios. e os child obJects são independentes. ou seJa existe qualquer tipo de relação hierárquica e os obJectos podem ser chamados independentemente uns a partir dos outros

em agregação temos apenas um único dono. os obJectos tem tempo de vida independente. e os child obJects  pertencem a um único parent. ou seJa existe uma espécie de ligação hierárquica to do tipo unilateral. apesar de os obJectos ainda serem minimamente independetntes

composição é idêntica a agregação mas o tempo de vida é o do dono. ou seJa. se o dono for parado. ou outros também o são

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit