# Acessar atributos de um vetor de objetos de outra classe usando ponteiros C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, ponteiro, array

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade em que tenho que montar um programa para gerenciar um restaurante que só faz entregas os pedidos são feitos por telefone e internet usando orientação a objetos e ponteiros em C++.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

Uso dois arquivos para cada classe um `.cpp` e um `.hpp`, abaixo minha implementação classe Cliente.

Cliente.hpp

```
#ifndef CLIENTE_HPP
#define CLIENTE_HPP

#include "Principal.hpp"
#include "Bibliotecas.hpp"

class Cliente {

    public:
        Cliente();

        int idCliente;
        string enderecoCliente;
        string nomeCliente;
        string cpfCliente;

        void inserirCliente();
        void alterarCliente();
        void listarCliente();
        void incrementaVetor();
        int excluirCliente();
        int pesquisar(int id);        

        virtual ~Cliente();
    protected:
    private:
        Cliente *clientes;
        Principal *principal;
        int TAM;
        int cont;
        int indice;
};

#endif // CLIENTE_HPP
```

Cliente.cpp

```
include "Cliente.hpp"

Cliente::Cliente() {

    idCliente = 0;
    enderecoCliente = "";
    nomeCliente = "";
    cpfCliente = "";

    TAM = 2;
    cont = 1;
    indice = 0;

    clientes =  NULL;
    principal = new Principal();
}

void Cliente::inserirCliente() {

    if(clientes == NULL) {
        clientes = new Cliente[TAM];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    principal->centralizaTexto("Cadastro de Clientes");
    cout << "\n";

    cout << endl << endl;
    principal->alinhaTexto("ID Cliente: ", 5, 14);
    cout << cont << endl;
    clientes[indice].idCliente = cont;
    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    do {
        principal->alinhaTexto("Informe o nome: ", 6, 14);
        getline(cin, clientes[indice].nomeCliente);
        cout << endl;
    } while(clientes[indice].nomeCliente == "");

    do {
        principal->alinhaTexto("Informe o endereço: ", 6, 14);
        getline(cin, clientes[indice].enderecoCliente);
        cout << endl;
    } while(clientes[indice].enderecoCliente == "");

    do {
        principal->alinhaTexto("Informe o número do CPF: ", 6, 14);
        getline(cin, clientes[indice].cpfCliente);
        cout << endl;
    } while(clientes[indice].cpfCliente == "");

    cont++;
    indice++;

    if(indice == TAM) {
        incrementaVetor();
    }

    cout << endl;
    principal->centralizaTexto("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", 10);
    principal->pause();
}

int Cliente::excluirCliente()  { ... }

void Cliente::alterarCliente() { ... }

void Cliente::listarCliente() { ... }

void Cliente::incrementaVetor()  { ... }

int Cliente::pesquisar(int id) {
    for(int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
        if (clientes[i].idCliente == id)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Tenho mais 2 classes implementadas dessa forma Cardápio e Motorista. Mas meu problema está na classe que tenho que fazer agora que é a classe Pedidos, nela eu preciso buscar as informações contidas nos vetores de objetos das outras classes (os vetores são ponteiros). Por exemplo preciso de dentro da classe Pedidos acessar a variável nomeCliente de um índice qualquer do vetor clientes para pegar seu conteúdo.

Minha classe Pedidos por enquanto esta assim:

Pedidos.hpp

```
#ifndef PEDIDOS_HPP
#define PEDIDOS_HPP

#include "Principal.hpp"
#include "Bibliotecas.hpp"
#include "Cliente.hpp"

class Pedidos {
    public:
        Pedidos();

        int idPedido;
        string clientePedido;
        string motoristaPedido;
        string itemsPedido;
        string placaVeiculoPedido;

        void inserirPedido();
        void alterarPedido();
        void listarPedido();
        void incrementaVetor();
        int excluirPedido();
        int pesquisar(int id);

        virtual ~Pedidos();
    protected:
    private:
        Cliente *clientes;
};

#endif // PEDIDOS_HPP
```

Pedidos.cpp

```
#include "Pedidos.hpp"
#include "Cliente.hpp"

Pedidos::Pedidos() {
    idPedido = 0;
    clientePedido = "";
    motoristaPedido = "";
    itemsPedido = "";
    placaVeiculoPedido = "";
}

void Pedidos::inserirPedido() {

}

void Pedidos::alterarPedido() {}
void Pedidos::listarPedido() {}
void Pedidos::incrementaVetor() {}
int Pedidos::excluirPedido() {}
int Pedidos::pesquisar(int id) {}

Pedidos::~Pedidos() {
    //dtor
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas, algumas davam erro de acesso e fechavam o programa outras o programa continuava mas não exibia o resultado.

Outra duvida é quanto a minha função de pesquisa que esta na classe `Cliente`, como faço para ele retornar um objeto do tipo ponteiro?

Comment: A pergunta está muito extensa, tente atacar um problema por vez, não faça a gente analisar todo seu código. Dê uma lida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Precisamos saber onde está seu problema. A gente ter que descobrir o problema para depois dar a solução fica complicado. Há um requisito de uso de ponteiro ou você decidiu usá-lo? Eu já vi algumas concepções erradas como a classe `Cliente` ter dentro dela `clientes`, que é uma coleção de `Cliente`. Em tese poderia, mas não soa esquisito clientes possuírem clientes? Quando a coisa está mal concebida a implementação também estará.

Comment: A pergunta esta da menor forma que achei pra mostrar meu problema, os primeiros códigos Clientes.hpp e Clientes.cpp não tem problemas e só pra ver como esta minha implementação e ocultei muito do meu código ai num tem nem 1/5 dele. Logo no inicio eu falo que preciso usar ponteiros porque e um requisito do trabalho. Bem entre os códigos esta meu problema real que é acessar as informações que estão nas outras classes como a clientes de dentro da classe pedidos. Minha classe Cliente possui um vetor chamado clientes onde estão os dados de cada um dos meus clientes.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que esta pergunta está longe de poder ser respondida como você deseja, e mesmo que esta resposta não responda o que foi perguntado eu vou tentar te colocar no caminho correto para depois vermos problemas específicos.

Vejo um grave erro em ter um ponteiro para `Cliente` dentro da própria classe `Cliente`. Embora tecnicamente isto seja possível em poucos casos faz sentido fazer isto. E mesmo não conhecendo seu exercício acho esquisito que isto seja necessário, cliente é cliente, coleção de clientes é algo totalmente separado.

Por falar nisto, já que está programando em C++ por que não usar [`Vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) no lugar do ponteiro, ele tem inúmeras vantagens.

É requisito do trabalho? Tem certeza? Está escrito isto? Tem algum motivo para o trabalho ter obrigatoriamente que ser feito do jeito errado?

Eu não sei o que faz a classe `Principal` mas eu duvido que precise ter uma instância dela dentro da classe `Cliente`, e provavelmente de qualquer outra. Talvez ela tenha sua utilidade de forma estática mas não como instância.

Não vou reclamar da mistura do uso de regras de negócio com interface com o usuário na mesma classe porque é um exercício, mas isto está errado conceitualmente e em código real nunca deveria ser feito desta forma.

Se houvesse esta simplificação seria mais fácil achar erros, ou talvez seria mais difícil cometê-los. Organização é fundamental em programação.

Ainda tem o erro de inicializar o *array* de clientes só quando for inserir algo nele, mas como isto já está todo errado nem acho que este seja o problema maior.

Também não faz sentido ter um *array* de `Cliente` ou mesmo um `Vector<Cliente>` dentro do pedido. Porque o pedido precisaria acessar todos os clientes?

Tem mais alguns pequenos problemas mas isto já dá uma ideia de como está complicado.

Sem resolver conceituações erradas vai ser difícil dar uma solução que realmente resolva alguma coisa. Claro que poderíamos dizer o que fazer em cima disto, mas o problema só aumentaria.

Pense em como as coisas realmente são. Entenda que `Pedido` é algo muito diferente de `Pedidos`. O segundo é composto por vários objetos do primeiro, há uma relação entre eles, mas são coisas distintas. Faça algo mais [coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) e entenda como fazer uma [agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).

Mesmo se fossemos ajudar em cima do exposto, ainda faltam informações que dê para dar uma resposta mais objetiva. Você ainda não tem um problema específico.

É o melhor que consigo ajudar agora.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Está explicito no trabalho para usar ponteiros pois e a matéria que estamos aprendendo. Não posso usar a Vector pois não foi passada ainda. O caso do ponteiro dentro do cliente foi uma orientação do próprio professor para resolver um  problema que tive antes assim como inicializar somente na hora de gravar os valores. A classe principal e uma coleção de funções que eu fiz por isso uso ela aqui e em outras classes. Basicamente preciso buscar informações na classe clientes e usa-la na classe pedido usando ponteiros "fazer as classes conversarem". Que informações precisa?

Comment: Lamento que estão te ensinando C++ como se fosse C. Ponteiro em C++ deve ser evitado até onde é possível sem perdas, que é o caso. P/ C++ ponteiro é um recursos avançado e não básico como é no C. Será que você entendeu a orientação do professor sobre o cliente ter clientes? Talvez até tenha entendido, pelo que está falando faz sentido uma ideia errada de como organizar classes. Do jeito que está eu não preciso de informações porque eu não saberia trabalhar com uma classe tão errada. Se não consertar o problema só vai aumentá-lo. Quando conceitua errado, implementa errado, não tem como escapar.

Comment: Tudo bem que tenha de ser evitado mas tenho que usar em algum momento para poder aprender, no caso esse trabalho. Senão quando precisar como faço. Como posso começar a consertar minhas classes para poder fazer o que preciso?

Comment: Aprender errado eu dispensaria. Guardaria o uso para quando fosse capaz de avaliar que ali o ponteiro é realmente útil, o que é bem raro. Tem gente que pode fazer uma aplicação e nunca usar um ponteiro. A resposta é justamente uma tentativa de mostrar os principais problemas que precisam de *redesign*. O principal é a mistura do `Cliente` com `Clientes`. Isto está tão errado que qualquer solução seria construir uma casa em cima de alicerce de barro. A classe `Pedidos` só está errada porque ela incluir os dados do pedido individual, deveria ser uma classe separada para isto.

Comment: A classe `Cliente` tem basicamente o mesmo erro mas o nome dá uma indicação mais errada, porque parece que é apenas um `Cliente`. Pode parecer pedantismo, mas se você dá nomes errados, dificulta entender o que aquilo representa. Você pode até saber, mas outras pessoas que vão ler seu código não saberão. E programar não é fazer o que você entende e sim o que todo mundo entende.

Comment: Mas como vou saber se e errado essa forma que meu professor ensina se não conheço nada, tenho que fazer meu trabalho usando ponteiros querendo ou não é o que foi pedido. Pode me dar um exemplo de como seria a maneira correta de fazer essas classes?

Comment: Pesquisando, estudando por conta própria, buscando fontes alternativas, desenvolvendo senso crítico. Se eu tiver tempo eu faço alguma coisa, mas não conte com isto. Estarei fazendo o trabalho para você. Um bom começo é a resposta da sua outra pergunta. Lá mostra como fazer certo. Leia o [tour] e a [help], especialmente [ask] e [help/on-topic].

Comment: E o que eu estou tentando fazer aqui postando meu código, tentando aprender e pesquisando mas a grande maioria do que acho sobre c++ e em inglês e fica um pouco difícil de entender. Uma única classe da forma correta você não esta fazendo meu trabalho, só estará me dando uma direção para continuar por conta própria.