# UML agregação X composição

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, uml

Estudando associações em UML ( agregação e composição) percebi que a diferença entre elas seria apenas a existência ou não das partes sem o todo.

http://ericksasse.com.br/agregao-x-composio/

- Agregação => Partes existem sem o todo
- Composição => Partes não existem sem o todo

As duas tratam de regras no objeto Parte, mas não encontrei nada que denotasse regras no objeto Todo, exemplo:

Um pedido (Todo) é composto por itens (Parte), não existem itens sem o todo (composição), a questão é que um pedido também não existe sem itens, como representar essa regra na UML? ou seja, onde digo que o objeto Todo também não existe sem o objeto Parte?

Comment: Dá uma lida em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101

Comment: Me parece q a única forma de alcançar o que eu citei é usando a multiplicidade, ou seja, uma declaração explicita.
Pedido deve ter  1..* itens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma questão interessante. Isso tem relação com o Caso de Uso - Cliente -> Faz Pedido. Descrevendo as principais funcionalidades do sistema e a interação dessas funcionalidades com os usuários do mesmo sistema. Este artefato é comumente derivado da especificação de requisitos, que por sua vez não faz parte da UML.
Porém, podemos expressar utilizando os padrões da UML para documentação de casos de uso.

Alguns livros informam que o todo não existe (ou não faz sentido) sem as partes.
Assim como a agregação, **você deve modelar uma composição quando o objetivo de seu modelo for descrever a estrutura de um relacionamento**. Uma composição mostra explicitamente o relacionamento estrutural todo/parte. Assim fica **subentendido** que: "o objeto Todo também não existe sem o objeto Parte".

Composição

- Uma variação do tipo agregação
- Representa um vínculo mais forte
  entre objetos-todo e objetos-parte
- Objetos-parte têm que pertencer ao
  objeto-todo
- **O todo não existe (ou não faz sentido)
  sem as partes**
- Ou, as partes não existem sem o todo