# Associação entre classes ou herança?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, herança, composição

Qual a melhor maneira de criar uma associação ou herança onde tenho a classe `Usuário` e a classe `Acadêmico` sendo que `Acadêmico` é um `Usuário`?

Classe usuário:

```
public  class Usuario 

    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Matricula { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Classe acadêmico:

```
 public class Academico 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Professor Professor { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Associação costuma ser melhor que herança.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo prático pra me indicar ?

Comment: Em C# não tenho de prontidão. Mas daqui a pouco aparece alguém que tem.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que um acadêmico não é um usuário, embora pareça ser. Se não é mesmo, não cabe herança. Dá para forçar que isso seja verdade, e alguns vão dizer que é, mas eu não iria por esse lado.

Um acadêmico circunstancialmente assume a capacidade de ser um usuário. Me parece que não são [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) relacionados diretamente um como filho do outro, mas sim que se interpõem em determinado momento, eles apenas se associam.

As pessoas tendem a olhar as relações de forma a achar coisas em comum, mas que não são a mesma coisa, são duas coisas diferentes que funcionam juntas. Nesse caso a associação é mais interessante.

O que é melhor para esse caso não sei dizer porque não conheço tudo sobre o problema. Tem algumas opções.

A mais óbvia é associar o acadêmico com o usuário criando uma propriedade ou mesmo um campo que indique qual é o perfil de usuário que ele deve adotar. Desta forma você faz a tal da [composição no lugar da herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101). Assim quando precisa usar um acadêmico adota esse tipo. Já se precisa das informações de usuário que ele tem usará o tipo do usuário, com a facilidade de ter um acesso direto a ele.

Eventualmente pode querer fazer uma associação bidirecional e facilitar o acesso do acadêmico por parte do usuário. Não gosto disso e pode trazer problemas futuros se mudar alguns conceitos.

Já pensou que um usuário poderia ser um acadêmico e alguma outra coisa ao mesmo tempo? Mesmo que isso não seja verdade hoje, nunca acontecerá?

Pode ser que o correto seria ter um outro objeto que associe os diversos papéis que ele assume.

Por isso que modelar corretamente no início é importante e deve dar flexibilidade para mudar do que jeito que for. Você não controla o mundo. Dá para arriscar que o dia sempre terá 24 horas, mesmo isso pode mudar, ainda que quase impossível, mas um dia alguém pode inventar que deve ter uma medida decimal para o dia e for aceito assim. Mas relações de papéis pode mudar fácil. Se mudar, tem que remodelar todo o sistema? Praticamente rescrever tudo que envolve isso?

Por outro lado eu posso estar errado, tenho pouca informação sobre o problema, e mesmo que tivesse bastante eu poderia ainda estar errado. Algum grau de risco sempre temos.

Uma das coisas que muitas pessoas não entendem sobre orientação a objeto é que o paradigma deve facilitar a modelagem do sistema dando a chance de mudar qualquer parte sem maiores traumas. Só conceituando muito bem é que chega nisso, **o código é só um detalhe**.

Também não estou dizendo que todo sistema mereça esse esforço. Nem sempre cabe todo preciosismo.

Se fizer herança nesse caso me parece esquisito, mas não está absurdamente errado como ocorre em muitos exemplos que vemos por aí onde a pessoa usa herança para juntar carro com banana porque em determinado momento ela precisa usar os dois no mesmo lugar. Se isso ocorrer acho que um dos `Id`s torna-se desnecessário.

Então acho que seria algo assim:

```
public class Academico {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Professor Professor { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

ou

```
public class Academico {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Professor Professor { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Association3.cs).

Note que usuário parece mais uma composição e o professor é uma associação. Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).

Answer (score 0):

Vamos analisar alguns cenários possíveis de modelagem do seu exemplo e considerar prós e contras.

**Caso relacione Academico e Usuario com herança**, vejo 3 efeitos negativos:

1. Haverá um aumento no acoplamento entre as duas classes (permitir que Academico acesse os atributos de Usuario apenas por meio de Getters e Setters protegidos é uma forma de reduzir este acoplamento, pois dá uma maior liberdade de alteração da estrutura interna de Usuario sem afetar Academico);
2. Você bloqueia a hierarquia de herança de Academico em linguagens com apenas herança simples - Academico não poderá herdar de outra classe, se necessário;
3. Quanto ao reuso, será que sempre fará sentido dizer que um acadêmico é um usuário? Este, em especial, é um ponto a analisar com menor ênfase, afinal, você nunca vai conseguir definir um modelo OO 100% reutilizável.

Como efeito positivo, você pode utilizar um objeto de Academico no lugar de uma referência de Usuario (poliformismo). Aqui, um ponto importante a considerar é o [Princípio de Substituição de Liskov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov). Em todo lugar que uma referência de usuário for usada, faria sentido usar uma instância de Academico?

**Outra modelagem possível** seria associar Academico com Usuario. Neste caso, opinião minha apenas, seria conveniente renomear usuário para algo como CredencialAcesso, por uma questão de semântica - Um acadêmico tem uma credencial de acesso.

Com isso, você reduz um pouco o acoplamento entre as duas classes (uma mudança na API de CredencialAcesso não precisa implicar numa mudança da API de Academico) e também não bloqueia a classe Academico para um relacionamento de herança. Ainda, quanto ao reuso, você poderia ter uma classe mais genérica Academico, sem o relacionamento com Usuario (essa seria a classe Academico com maior grau de reuso). Para o sistema que estiver modelando no momento, poderia criar uma subclasse dessa, AcademicoFaculdade (apenas um exemplo), que está relacionada com CredencialAcesso (ou Usuario, como preferir).

Perceba que a vantagem que você tinha com a herança (polimorfismo) ainda pode ser obtida por meio de interfaces.

Apesar dos efeitos negativos da herança não existirem no caso da associação, dois pontos precisam ser observados:

1. Você deverá ter um mecanismo extra para garantir que, em memória, dois ou mais acadêmicos não se associem à mesma credencial (se o domínio não permitir isso) - embora talvez isso seja minimizado por uma validação existente durante a persistência (eventualmente você terá o objeto em estado inválido na memória - o que não é legal - mas isso será descoberto no momento da persistência);
2. Caso queira usar os métodos pertinentes à Usuario dentro de Academico, terá: ou que invocar algo como academico.Usuario.Nome, o que abre um pouco do encapsulamento de Academico; ou que criar métodos em Academico que delegam para os métodos já definidos em Usuario (o que aumenta o acoplamento entre as classes).

Não dá para dizer que tem uma solução mais correta que outra. Escolhendo A ou B, terá apenas que lidar com as implicações. Nos meus sistemas, particularmente, prefiro composição à herança quando possível.