# Uma subclasse pode ter duas superclasses?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Suponha que eu tenha uma superclasse `Pessoa` e outra `Funcionário`, com seus determinados atributos e métodos. Minha classe `Professor` pode ser "filha" de `Pessoa` e `Funcionário`, uma vez que ela se encaixa nas duas? Se sim como é possível? Com `extends` mesmo?

Comment: Não na modelagem do Java. Java prevê que cada classe só pode herdar de uma única classe mãe (mas pode ter classe avó, bisavó etc). Creio que uma modelagem mais carinhosa precisaria ser feita, possivelmente com mais classes e interfaces para conseguir entrar no mundo Java.

Comment: Se sua estrutura for baseada em interface, sendo pessoa e funcionario interfaces e nao implementacoes concretas, sim, é possivel. Caso contrario, não pois java não permite herança multipla.

Comment: Ela poderia herdar de Funcionário... Não seria necessário herdar de Pessoa também, tendo em vista que Funcionário é uma pessoa

Comment: @AndersonHenrique **se** funcionário for subclasse de pessoa...

Comment: Claro @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 14):

O que você está procurando chama-se [herança múltipla](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heran%C3%A7a_m%C3%BAltipla). Enquanto esse é certamente um mecanismo poderoso, herança múltipla abre portas para novos problemas (veja, por exemplo, [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233728/heran%C3%A7a-m%C3%BAltipla-e-problema-do-diamante) sobre o problema do diamante).

Java, por uma decisão de *design* dos autores da linguagem, suporta somente herança-simples.

Dito isso, Java permite que uma classe implemente múltiplas interfaces (e que uma interface estenda múltiplas outras interfaces). Desde o Java 8 Interfaces podem também conter métodos *default*. Combinando composição e Interfaces é possível "reaproveitar comportamento" sem ter que lidar com boa parte das desvantagens da herança-múltipla.

Comment: hahah obrigado pela resposta, me aprofundei nos conceitos de Herança e entendi a ideia, vlw parceiro

Answer (score 13):

A resposta do Anthony Accioly responde bem a pergunta, vou complementar.

[Java tem herança múltipla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101) de [subtipo, mas não de subclasse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101), ou seja, você pode ter vários tipos na sua classe, mas não pode ter várias implementações. Na verdade, desde Java 8 é possível ter várias implementações de comportamento ([método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212265/101)), mas não de estado ([variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)), através de [métodos padrões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101).

Herança múltipla completa quase nunca é necessária e [quase sempre está errada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/101), mal me lembro a última vez que vi um caso que precisava de herança múltipla, acho que era um problema de biologia. Técnicas de reuso são úteis, mas não tornam um tipo ser dois tipos completos, no máximo ter membros de dois tipos.

Dito isso, sinto lhe informar que quase todos os [exemplos que ensinam OOP são fracos e errados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205140/101) e por isso todo mundo aprende errado.

Seu exemplo é um clássico engano. [`Professor` não é uma `Pessoa` e `Funcionário`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245182/101), no máximo ele tem membros de um Pessoa e um Funcionário. Porque ao contrário do que pregam alguns, [orientação a objeto não consegue modelar o mundo real](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277179/101), ela consegue modelar uma abstração do mundo real. Não entenda `Pessoa` como um ser humano, e sim como uma ficha de uma pessoa, porque é isso que essa classe é. O mesmo do `Funcionário`. Funcionário é um conceito abstrato criado por humanos, não sendo concreto ele não existe no mundo real. E também é uma ficha de dados que uma pessoa que pessoas pode ter para uma função.

Se quisesse insistir em modelar como se fosse o mundo real é fácil resolver seu problema, basta hierarquizar corretamente. `Professor` herda de `Funcionário` que herda de `Pessoa`. Pronto resolvido seu problema, porque todo `Professor` é um `Funcionário`, certo? Todo `Funcionário` é uma `Pessoa`, certo?

Bom, errado, mas a hierarquia é uma solução para vários casos, não este.

No máximo um `Professor` pode ter dados e comportamentos que todo `Funcionário` e toda Pessoa tem. Então faz sentido ter [interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89275/101) ou [*traits*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101) (que é mais ou menos o que o Java 8 introduziu) ou [outras opções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101), ou seja, tem estes subtipos, mas não subclasses. Até [*mixins*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275897/101) podem ser úteis, mas Java não tem, então usa-se a [delegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87521/101).

Mesmo isso costuma estar errado. Uma pessoa pode ser `Professor` e `Aluno` ao mesmo tempo. Uma `Pessoa` pode ser `Funcionário` e `Cliente` ao mesmo tempo, como resolve isso? Simples, faça cada parte ser independente. Uma `Pessoa` é uma pessoa, nada mais que isso. Um `Funcionário` é um funcionário e um `Cliente` é um cliente, nada mais que isso e claro que um `Professor` é um professor e um `Aluno` é um aluno e nada mais que isto. Você faz [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101) entre eles fazendo uma [associação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101) da atividade que cada um está exercendo.

E nem entrei no mérito que um `Cliente` pode ser [`Pessoa Física` ou `Jurídica`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101).

Se você faz essa herança passa ter mais de uma ficha da pessoa no sistema, a informação deixa de ser canônica ([DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) de dados) e começa causar confusão. Parece coisa de TI público (homenagem ao Bacco).

A maioria dos dados são relacionados entre si e não herdados. Quase toda herança deveria ser de subtipo, e olhe lá, e parcialmente de comportamento. Quase toda herança deveria ser de [classe abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101) ou [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) (ou *trait*). Então uma `Pessoa Física` ou `Jurídica` herdam de `Pessoa`, legal, porque Pessoa por si só não existe, é só uma base para os tipos de pessoas. O que existe raramente faz sentido herdar, a não ser em biologia, [GUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), que é abstrato por definição, e alguns outros problemas.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.