# Como se modela um papel em orientação a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, uml, composição

Como normalmente se modela um papel (*role*) em orientação a objetos?

É por meio de uma composição, correto? Por exemplo, para modelar que uma `Pessoa` **executa o papel** de um `Cliente` ou `Fornecedor`, modela-se que a Pessoa **tem** um `Cliente`, ou um `Fornecedor`, etc.

Como fica isso na UML? E no código?

Como atua a delegação (*forwarding*) nessa história? ([Vide exemplo](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/herancavscomposicao.htm))

**Editado:** Isso que dá ficar só na teoria. Demorei a perceber que meu problema é `Cliente` ter uma `Pessoa` e não o contrário... pelo menos o contrário não é necessário a princípio. [Vide](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/tecnicas7.gif).

Comment: Eu sei formas de modelar, UML ñ sei ñ.

Comment: @Maniero Tudo bem, sem UML então :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma muito simplificada:

```
class Pessoa {
    string Nome;
}
class Cliente {
    Pessoa pessoa;
    decimal credito;
}
class Faturamento {
    Venda(Cliente cliente) => Write(cliente.pessoa.Nome);
}
```

Se desejar que pessoa tenha ciência dos papéis que ele exerce poderia fazer de duas formas:

```
class Pessoa {
    string Nome;
    Cliente cliente;
    Fornecedor fornecedor;
}
```

Cada papel que for adicionar precisa mudar a classe, o que viola alguns princípios, mas que nem sempre é um problema.

Outra forma:

```
enum TipoPapel { Cliente, Fornecedor }

class Pessoa {
    string Nome;
    List<(TipoPapel, IPapel)> papeis = new();
    AdicionaPapel(TipoPapel tipo, Ipapel papel) => papeis.Add((tipo, papel));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Person.cs).

Em vez de `enum` poderia usar `string` que pode facilitar ou dificultar, dependendo do caso. Poderia usar um dicionário no lugar da lista, ou outra estrutura, até mais especializada. E poderia usar um tipo específico no lugar da tupla. Poderia ter o controle dos papéis em um tipo separado que abstraísse a lista.

UML é uma das coisas mais trolhas que já vi, então não :)

Comment: Não entendi por que `Cliente` tem que implementar `Papel`. Ou melhor, por que a interface `Papel` precisa existir. Foi feito assim para poder modelar o dicionário ou tem algum método importante em `Papel`?

Answer (score 2):

Copiado da resposta do Maniero, só que em pseudo-Java, para visualizar melhor (e tome *boilerplate*. Quem tiver o que melhorar é só editar).

De forma muito simplificada:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
}

public interface Papel {
    void umMetodo();
}

public class Cliente implements Papel {
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private BigDecimal credito;
}

public class Faturamento {
    public void venda(Cliente cliente) {
        System.out.println(cliente.getPessoa().getNome());
    }
}
```

Se desejar que pessoa tenha ciência dos papéis que ele exerce poderia fazer de duas formas:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Fornecedor fornecedor;
}
```

Cada papel que for adicionar precisa mudar a classe, o que viola alguns princípios, mas que nem sempre é um problema.

Outra forma:

```
public enum TipoPapel { Cliente, Fornecedor }

public class Pessoa {
    private String Nome;
    private Map<TipoPapel, Papel> papeis = new HashMap<>();

    public void adicionaPapel(TipoPapel tipo, Papel papel) {
        papeis.put(tipo, papel);
    }
}
```

Em vez de enum poderia usar String que pode facilitar ou dificultar, dependendo do caso. Poderia usar outra estrutura, até mais especializada, no lugar do mapa. Poderia ter o controle dos papéis em um tipo separado que abstraísse o mapa.

Comment: O meu ainda deve ter alguns problemas, mas é pseudocódigo, este eu já vejo alguns problemas mais claros, e nem compilaria :)

Comment: Digamos que é pseudoJavaCódigo. :P

Comment: @Maniero Pelo menos não é UML, veja o lado bom...