# Salvar dados com herança em C#

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, asp.net-core, herança

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Aluno
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Ra { get; set; }
    public Decimal NotaB1 { get; set; }
    public Decimal NotaB2 { get; set; }


    public Decimal getMedia()
    {
        return (NotaB1 + NotaB2) / 2;
    }

}

 public class AlunoTecnologo : Aluno
{
    public Decimal NotaPim { get; set; }

    public Decimal getMedia()
    {
        return NotaPim * 0.2m + base.getMedia();
    }
}
```

Estou simulando a persistência dos dados em um BD, dessa maneira criei a seguinte classe onde eu crio uma lista para salvar os alunos em memória:

```
public class AlunoDao
{
    private List<Aluno> alunos;

    public AlunoDao()
    {
        alunos = new List<Aluno>();
    }

    public void Adicionar(Aluno aluno)
    {
        alunos.Add(aluno);
    }

    public List<Aluno> Listar()
    {
        return new List<Aluno>(alunos);
    }
}
```

Porém ao salvar um `AlunoTecnologo` nessa lista, a média é calculada com o método da classe **Aluno** e não da classe `AlunoTecnologo` onde uma nota a mais é inserida. Segue exemplo de como ficou o código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Aluno vizu = new Aluno()
        {
            Nome = "Joao Vizu",
            Ra = "N300361",
            NotaB1 = 7.5M,
            NotaB2 = 10M
        };

        AlunoTecnologo lais = new AlunoTecnologo()
        {
            Nome = "Lais Silva",
            Ra = "545454",
            NotaB1 = 7.5M,
            NotaB2 = 10M,
            NotaPim = 9M
        };

        AlunoDao dao = new AlunoDao();

        dao.Adicionar(vizu);
        dao.Adicionar(lais);

        foreach (Aluno aluno in dao.Listar())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {aluno.Nome}\tNotaB1: {aluno.NotaB1}\tNotaB2: {aluno.NotaB2}\tMedia: {aluno.getMedia()}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

O que devo fazer para que eu consiga adicionar nessa lista os dados corretos de cada aluno, seguindo a herança? Teria que criar uma classe DAO para o `AlunoTecnologo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso você não deve criar um novo DAO, afinal está usando herança. Dá até pra questionar se deveria ter essa herança por causa do [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), mas depende de alguns fatores que não sabemos sobre seu problema. Vou considerar que a herança é realmente necessária (eu acho que a modelagem está errada, mas é um erro que quase todo mundo comete e acham que está certo por isso não vou focar nesse ponto).

O DAO é para cuidar dos alunos, não importa quais, então ele está correto. O que você precisa é de [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101), assim o método correto será chamado.

Vamos consertar alguns outros problemas do código? Não vou corrigir todos, por exemplo não irei criar [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var vizu = new Aluno() {
            Nome = "Joao Vizu",
            Ra = "N300361",
            NotaB1 = 7.5M,
            NotaB2 = 10M
        };
        var lais = new AlunoTecnologo() {
            Nome = "Lais Silva",
            Ra = "545454",
            NotaB1 = 7.5M,
            NotaB2 = 10M,
            NotaPim = 9M
        };
        var dao = new AlunoDao();
        dao.Adicionar(vizu);
        dao.Adicionar(lais);
        foreach (Aluno aluno in dao.Listar()) WriteLine($"Nome: {aluno.Nome}\tNotaB1: {aluno.NotaB1}\tNotaB2: {aluno.NotaB2}\tMedia: {aluno.Media}");
    }
}

public class Aluno {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Ra { get; set; }
    public decimal NotaB1 { get; set; }
    public decimal NotaB2 { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Media => (NotaB1 + NotaB2) / 2;
}

 public class AlunoTecnologo : Aluno {
    public decimal NotaPim { get; set; }
    public override decimal Media => NotaPim * 0.2m + base.Media;
}

public class AlunoDao {
    private List<Aluno> alunos;
    public AlunoDao() => alunos = new List<Aluno>();
    public void Adicionar(Aluno aluno) => alunos.Add(aluno);
    public List<Aluno> Listar() => new List<Aluno>(alunos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Cg6KDD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9gVLjp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Polimorphism.cs).

Fiz mudanças que usam uma forma mais limpa e moderna de codificar além de seguir padrões de nomenclatura do C#. Mas o que importa para você aí é tornar o método virtual, assim ele pode ser escolhido entre o método do objeto real e não ao tipo geral que está declarado na lista. Estude o assunto para entender melhor o mecanismo.

Fiz essa propriedade porque é o jeito mais adequado e idiomático do C#, o jeito feito na pergunta é coisa de outra linguagem.

Em um banco de dados você terá que ter uma tabela única com todos os campos usados em todas tabelas derivadas de `Aluno`. Ou então ter tabelas separadas, aí cai no que eu disse que a herança talvez não seja o caso. Se fizer várias tabelas não deverá usar herança. As pessoas não entendem a implicação da herança e como isto não pode ser realizado corretamente em um banco de dados (até pode, mas fica sem sentido, você terá uma tabela apenas com referências para outras). Pode ser que o que deseja é implementar [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) e não herança. Este tipo de herança nem sempre encaixa bem no mundo real e facilita cometer alguns erros, isto se ele não violar Liskov.

Se abandonar a herança aí seria o caso de ter 2 ou mais DAOs ou adotar algo mais adequado porque aí passa ter coisas completamente separadas, aina que relacionadas, você passa ter um modelo relacional.

Por vezes questiono o uso de DAOs, neste caso ficou claro que está usando como abstração e no momento está fazendo só na memória mas um dia quer poder trocar para o banco de dados. O problema é que nem sempre o modelo que deu certo na memória dará certo no banco de dados, por isso que eu falo que a generalização não é tão simples quanto as pessoas imaginam. Explico em detalhes sobre em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401729/101).

Answer (score 0):

Sim você precisa criar uma outra "Dao" e também outra tabela.

Veja que a herança funciona bem, acontece que, na sua Dao você uma lista de `Aluno`, e ele aceita um `AlunoTecnologico` porque este herda de `Aluno`, mas o objeto será tratado como `Aluno`, ou seja, vai usar o método `getMedia`de `Aluno`, por isso não calcula como você espera, e nem deveria, porque  a classe `Aluno` não tem a propriedade `NotaPim`, obviamente daria um erro :)

Além disso, falando em BD, sua tabela "Aluno" não deve ter um atributo "NotaPim", por isso vai perder esse valor.

Para o seu exemplo, a solução mais simples de implementar/entender pode ser criar duas tabelas e duas classes "DAO", para Aluno e AlunoTecnologico. Você não disse qual o banco de dados está usando, mas em geral BD não implementa essa estrutura de herança, então melhor cada entidade separada.

Você claro pode fazer uma solução mais elaborada e mais correta do ponto de vista de modelo:

Criar a tabela "Aluno", a tabela "AlunoTecnologico" e essa ter só os atributos que não tem em "Aluno", ou seja, "NotaPim", e adicionar uma chave para "Aluno".

Veja que estou assumindo que está usando um banco de dados relacional (`mysql`, `sql-server`, `oracle`, etc).  Daí colocar a lógica para gravar em ambas as tabelas e também recuperar o valor de ambas na "DAO", mas isso daria bem mais trabalho, como está estudando `C#`, talvez não seja a melhor opção para esse momento.