# Declarar uma classe como atributo ou implementar abstract?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Tem-se uma Televisão da marca LG. nesse esquema posso ter diferentes tipos de televisões e diferentes tipo de eletrônicos (de maneira que o sistema possa crescer e eu possa usar ele não só para o seguimento de eletrônicos, mas também para o seguimento têxtil e alimentício)

Qual é a maneira mais correta para descrever essa situação?

**Maneira 1**

// Pode-se ser Eletrônico, ou posteriormente um novo tipo como Roupa, Comida ...

```
public class Tipo {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Descricao {get;set;}
}
```

// Podendo ser a marca do meu eletrônico, ou posteriormente um tipo de Roupa ou Comida

```
public class Marca {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Descricao {get;set;}
   public Tipo Tipo {get;set;}
}
```

// Onde esse item pode ser uma Televisão, ou uma Camisa e até mesmo um Chocolate.

```
public class Item {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Descricao {get;set;}
   public Marca Marca {get;set;}
}
```

Dessa forma eu consigo notar que fiz a **OO** o mais genérico possível, porém no momento da criação do **item** é possível notar que produtos com marcas diferentes possam ter atributos diferentes. por exemplo, um eletrônico pode ter o atributo voltagem, onde a roupa e a comida não teria. levando esse argumento em questão, é possível falar que a ideia mais correto seria:

**Maneira 2**

// Os tipos

```
public abstract class Eletronico {
    public int IdTipo {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoTipo {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Roupa {
    public int IdTipo {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoTipo {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Comida {
    public int IdTipo {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoTipo {get;set;}
}
```

// As Marcas onde pertencem a um tipo

```
public abstract class LG : Eletronico {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Samsung : Eletronico {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Versace : Roupa {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Lascote: Roupa {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}

public abstract class McDonalds: Comida {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}

public abstract class BurguerKing: Comida {
    public int IdMarca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoMarca {get;set;}
}
```

// E agora sim os nossos itens

```
public class TelevisaoLG : LG {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public int Polegadas {get;set;}
    public int Voltagem {get;set;}
}

public class TelevisaoSamsung : Samsung {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public int Polegadas {get;set;}
    public int Voltagem {get;set;}
    public bool Suporte4k {get;set;}
}

public class Camiseta : Lacoste {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public int Tamanho {get;set;}
}

public class LancheWhooper : BurguerKing {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public int Calorias {get;set;}
}
```

Dessa maneira a **oo** fica mais extensão mas dessa forma é mais fácil identificar um menor acoplamento entre as classes.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual é a maneira mais correta a se fazer? Da maneira 1 ou maneira 2?
- Existe uma maneira melhor, se sim como?
- Da maneira 2, o jeito correto é usar mesmo o método `abstract` nos
  tipos e marcas? e é possível fazer uma classe `abstract` implementar
  outra classe `abstract`?
- Levando em consideração que a **Maneira 2** seja a mais adequada e
  temos os seguintes tipos como exemplo: `Eletronico`, `Roupa`, `Comida`.
  então tenho uma classe para cada um. Agora o sistema também irá
  trabalhar com um novo tipo `Automobilistico` para que os usuários
  possam utilizar vou ter que atualizar meu projeto criando uma classe
  `Automobilistico` (Tipo)? e gerar todas as Marcas e Itens de maneira
  manual? Porque na **Maneira 1** o modo mais genérico facilita de
  modo a criar apenas o tipo `Automobilistico` na minha base de dados
  e adicionar também as marcas e os itens na base de dados. Como isso
  ficaria na **Maneira 2**?

Comment: essa "maneira 2" me parece totalmente sem sentido. Isso iria gerar um modelo que, quando precisar de uma marca nova vai precisar gerar mais uma nova classe, o que é ruim, e ainda uma TV de outra marca vai ter as mesmas propriedades, então isso iria gerar um monte de código duplicado, por isso não faz sentido. A "maneira 1" é bem mais adequada

Comment: além disso, seus exemplos estão bem confusos, misturando TV, roupa, comida... afinal o que vc quer modelar? primeiro pense em tudo que seu sistema deve ter... vai ter TV? outro eletrônico? escreva cada um e suas características (nome, cor, modelo, etc). Veja tudo que é comum. Se tiver ao menos uma propriedade que seja comum a todos, pode ser possível gerar um classe mais "genérica", como Item, dai herdar dela e modelar as outras, mas se foque só no que precisa, senão fica difícil para vc e para quem ler te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de começar tenho que dizer que [o que chama de atributo na verdade se chama campo e o que está usando de fato é nenhum dos dois, é a propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Também tenho que alertar que está tentando fazer algo que não é simples. Parece simples e pode dar certo de início, mas no momento que for usar para os tipos de produto reais pode não dar tão certo assim. Generalização sempre é complicada e só dá certo se você tiver muito controle da situação e entendimento profundo da sua utilização. Em geral as pessoas não tem as duas coisas, especialmente em domínio de negócios, experiência própria.

## Modelos

Também em boa parte dos casos que se usa esse tipo de modelagem que os objetos passam ter identidade na própria classe e não no objeto (segunda maneira) não funciona bem e eu tenho quase certeza que é um exemplo artificial que se assemelha ao que é mostrado em livros, que são exemplos para mostrar os mecanismos de orientação a objeto, mas são péssimos para modelar aplicações reais. Então acho que está aprendendo OO acadêmico que não serve para o que se usa de verdade. Se você lidar com milhares de produtos diferentes no estoque, terá milhares de classes? Se fizer isto será o sistema mais confuso que já vi na vida e só dá certo como exercício (do que não fazer mesmo parecendo que é certo).

Jeito certo depende dos requisitos detalhados, que nós não temos. Espero que você os tenha para tomar boas decisões. Mas pelo que eu disse já dá uma indicação que a primeira maneira parece mais sensata para boa parte dos casos.

A solução correta parece passar por um mecanismo que controle os produtos de forma genérica e tenha um mecanismo para lidar com as diferenças específicas, algo que pode ser bem sofisticado, mas de qualquer forma parece caso de composição e não herança, como quase tudo o que fazemos. As pessoas aprendem OO e se deslumbram com herança, mas quase sempre ela viola o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) e causa problemas.

O máximo que eu consigo pensar, e isto já pode ser um exagero, é ter uma classe abstrata `Produto` e algumas concretas que sejam alguns poucos tipos de produtos que tem muita diferença como `Automovel` ou e `Eletronico`. Mas só posso dar uma solução entendendo todos os aspectos do problema, o que faria esta ser uma pergunta bem ampla.

## Solução real

O código parece ter outros problemas de tipagem, como por exemplo usar `int` para voltagem. Este é um dado [descritivo e não quantitativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101), então não faz sentido ele ser numérico apenas porque a descrição só envolve dígitos. O tamanho piorou porque é comum usar letras, e estes são só dois exemplos, quase todos os outros estão errados também. Claro, se ainda for usar isto, eu não usaria assim. E justamente porque em geral esses dados serem só descritivos e você não tem que fazer nenhuma operação específica com eles um mecanismo genérico de manter várias descrições pode ser muito mais adequado do que ter propriedades específicas em objetos, assim apenas teria uma propriedade de conjunto de descrições genéricas com o famoso par de chave (o que está descrevendo) e valor (a descrição em si daquela sub propriedade), quem sabe usando um dicionário que tem chave-valor.

Pra mim você tem um caso de um `Produto` que segue o modelo tradicional e tem uma série se sub propriedades puramente descritivas que variam de acordo com o produto. Por serem adornos ao objeto elas deveriam ser configuradas conforme o produto. Em um banco de dados usaria uma coluna JSON, XML, *array*, ou *string* com formato específico para gravar tudo isto. Algumas pessoas criariam uma *string* que funciona como um t6exto livre para colocar todas essas descrições como uma coisa só. Não acho que fica bom, mas não é uma solução terrível em alguns casos.

Uma outra forma de pensar isto é ter uma propriedade que é uma referência para outro objeto (ou outra tabela no banco de dados) e aí nesse objeto teria os dados específicos, a diferença para a solução anterior é que teria uma classe diferente para cada produto. Ainda teria muitas classes, mas pelo menos não muitos produtos, o que manteria os dados mais organizados tendo um ponto central de produtos que se referenciam para objetos específicos só na parte específica, funciona como um [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101). Mas isso só vale se os dados devem ter funcionalidade específica além de descrição, não acho que seja o caso.

Se tem realmente essa necessidade então a herança pode não ser o fim do mundo. Mas pode complicar porque parece que teria que fazer combinações de propriedades e teria que reimplementar algumas coisas porque C# não tem herança múltipla (as linguagens que possuem não recomendam e não soluciona o problema tão bem)

Claro que se estas sub propriedades precisam de operações específicas e não só serão apresentados de forma básica então começa complicar, mas aí entramos no campo da especulação, nada indica que precisa disto e até que tenha clara indicação e com detalhes de como proceder em cada caso melhor nem pensar nisto.

## Problemas artificiais

Se o "problema" for artificial quase sempre sairá errado. Ou ele é inerentemente certo porque se foi inventado qualquer coisa pode ser feita e estar certo, o difícil é fazer ao que se sustente no mundo real com requisitos que mudam sem seu controle.

Pra falar a verdade este exemplo é complexo e sem requisitos muito bem coletados e sem experiência a chance disso dar errado é grande. Vai funcionar em primeiro momento, quando for expandir vai começar mostrar os problemas que parece ser o que tem maior preocupação, mas dei várias dicas do que pode ser o caminho.

Comment: Olá Maniero sua resposta foi quase tão complexa quanto minha pergunta. kkkkk


A ideia dessa abordagem OO é um caso no qual tive dúvidas hoje, do que seria "correto"

Se você lidar com milhares de produtos diferentes no estoque, terá milhares de classes? - Concordo plenamente, sem falar na dificuldade em adicionar um novo Produto.

Com relação aos requisitos a ideia em que eu pensei, era um sistema de Varejo onde posso ter uma variedade enorme de produtos/marcas/tipos e levando em consideração a variedade de produtos.

Comment: Afinal, seria estranho um produto do tipo "Arroz" ter uma propriedade Voltagem, não é ? Como você lidaria com isso?

Comment: Levando em consideração sua resposta, não consigo pensar em outro jeito a não ser a Maneira 1, ter tudo generico e talvez usar apenas em alguns produtos.

Comment: Eu não acho que consigo acrescentar algo a mais, porque sem um problema bem definido não dá para ter uma boa solução. É o que eu falo, se você não sabe onde quer chegar qualquer lugar serve e qualquer lugar pode ser o errado porque aí descobre que não queria ir ali. Eu falei como eu lidaria com propriedades diversas, releia a resposta. Eu posso até melhorar alguma coisa na resposta, mas não sairá muito disto.