# Quando devo usar a generalização em caso de uso?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, herança, casos-de-uso

- Para que serve a generalização no caso de uso?
- Quando devo a generalização?
- Se eu possuo 2 atores, um aluno e o outro professor, eles são respectivamente usuários, então entraria a parte da generalização?

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Advantages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há alguma controvérsia sobre isso. Existe uma "escola" que pensa de uma forma e ela é a mais acadêmica possível, de fato é a usada em praticamente todo exemplo de livro, blog, curso ou outra forma que vê por aí de como fazer a generalização. E existe a "escola" pragmática que tenta pensar em como as coisas realmente são e assim pode dar uma chance maior de não ter problemas no futuro. Inclusive essas pessoas entendem que herança, e portando a generalização é quase um *anti pattern* hoje em dia e que algumas pessoas já percebem que se tiver que generalizar deveria ser com uma classe abstrata ou interface (ou *trait* onde isto existe), ou seja, uma classe concreta não pode ser a generalização.

Então seu exemplo segue a "escola" acadêmica (sem trocadilhos com o domínio do exemplo). Ela acredita que um mesmo objeto real pode existir em várias instâncias do sistema, seja na mesma linha de especialização, seja na mais geral, e mais ainda, pode existir em linhas diferentes, portanto usa uma herança de um objeto concreto em um outro objeto. Minha experiência e já corroborada com muita gente que conheço que não são seguidores de receita de bolo que acredita que o que está nos livros sirva para algo real é que isto não existe e causa problemas na modelagem.

Quem é pragmático sabe que aluno, professor e usuário são coisas distintas, e em geral são [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) que pessoas exercem no sistema (ou organização). Uma pessoa é composta, entre outras coisas, por seus papéis, ou então um papel é composto, entre outras coisas, por uma pessoa. Em composição não há generalização. Eventualmente um papel poderia ser uma generalização desses papéis específicos, mas nem costumo enxergar assim porque não vejo o que um papel tem em comum um com outro, mas é algo possível. Se a generalização for feita em algum fato específico pode ser através de interfaces. Dar uma capacidade geral a um ator é algo que acontece mais que a generalização mais geral.

Então o caso de uso precisa considerar o que aquele objeto pode fazer e se tem outros objetos que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa, ainda que com específicas dele, aí existe alguma forma de generalização, mas por completo, apenas nesta característica específica. Então aluno e professor podem ter algo que eles façam em comum de forma igual e isso permite uma generalização parcial, mas eles não são especificidades de um ator e sim de uma ação.

Uma generalização que eu vejo sempre é uma pessoa ser uma generalização de pessoa física e pessoa jurídica, onde a primeira seria abstrata e as demais concretas, mantendo aquela ideia que o objeto mais geral não pode ser concreto.

Na "escola" acadêmica basta ter alguma coisa em comum que já deveria fazer a generalização. Este grupo de pessoas acha que, pelo menos em alguns casos, se você tem um nome em dois objetos já pode generalizar porque tem algo em comum, mesmo que esse nome nada tenha a ver com o outro nome. Eles ignoram o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

O que eu vejo é que é preciso muita experiência para saber fazer generalização, e portanto programar orientado a objeto, porque não é fácil enxergar quando deve fazer ou não sem saber o que dá problema. É preciso muita experiência com taxonomia e até ontologia e quem sabe dialética. Você pode estudar essas coisas, mas só a experiência te dá boas condições de lidar com isso. Cada vez mais acredito que OOP só deveria ser introduzido para programadores depois de certo tempo, quem sabe quando está fazendo a transição de júnior para pleno e o exercício desta disciplina realmente acontecer só quando a pessoa é sênior (de verdade, não só que tenha o título), que não cometem esses erros de academicismo com tanta facilidade.

Uma coisa que eu falo muito é que precisa ter muita clareza do que está fazendo. Vou dar um exemplo: você coloca a palavra respectivamente, mas não tem nada respectivo ali, então mesmo que inconscientemente já está vendo o problema de uma forma que ele não é. Claro que pode rever isto, mas se ninguém mais experiente falar provavelmente vai cometer algum erro na modelam com isso. Por isso algumas têm dificuldade para evoluir a aprender, elas não querem ouvir quem é mais experiente, quem pode dar um parâmetro e mostra onde ela está errando. É claro que a pessoa não deve confiar cegamente em tudo o que dizem pra ela também, porque todo mundo pode errar, tem que criar sua própria consciência, isso leva tempo.

Então aí você primeiro tem que escolher que "escola" vai seguir. A pragmática faz aprender mais rápido, mas ela não é bem vista em certos círculos que ainda compra a ideia da academia e tende a classificar como errada se não segue o que está nos livros.

Comment: Eu subi os requisitos e na hora de modelar eu fiquei muito na dúvida se era melhor usar generalização ou não, pois assim, **exemplo:** um aluno pode ver suas notas, e os professores também podem ver as notas do aluno, nesse caso eu pensei em generalizar, mas como você disse que é quase um anti-pattern é bem difícil usar isso na prática (conforme o sistema aumenta). Em relação a POO nesse caso, eu acho que acabei me "viciando" negativamente em POO, sendo que consigo enxergar apenas ele como a solução de meus problemas.

Comment: @RodrigoPires o primeiro passo para a cura é reconhecer a doença :) Então você já está na frente de muita gente. OOP é difícil porque exige que modele certo, o que é complicado para a maioria das pessoas. Então quem não é tão experiente vai cometer muito erro fazer mais coisa complicada que o normal.

Answer (score 2):

Generalização em casos de uso é análoga à generalização em banco de dados ou orientação a objetos (que chamamos de herança).

Quando se fala em atores, vários atores podem desempenhar o mesmo papel em um caso de uso específico. A generalização é como se representa isto, um ator pode "herdar" características de outro.

> Se eu possuo 2 atores, um aluno e o outro professor, eles são respectivamente usuários, então entraria a parte da generalização?

Não, necessariamente. Isso vai depender das regras da aplicação. Pra todo efeito, todos os atores primários serão usuários do sistema (que vão interagir por meio de algum tipo de interface gráfica). Generalização tem a mais com compartilhamento de características.

Pense nos atores como sendo papéis específicos que acessam determinadas ações e um usuário do sistema pode desempenhar diferentes papéis.

Pra ilustrar o que eu quero dizer, aqui vai um pequeno exemplo. Imagine que estamos criando o diagrama de casos de uso para uma biblioteca de uma escola e temos as seguintes regras:

> - Alunos e Professores podem reservar livros
> - Alunos e Professores podem pesquisar o catálogo de livros
> - Professores podem solicitar novos livros

Note que, tudo que os alunos podem fazer, os professores também podem. Dessa forma, poderíamos usar a generalização e fazer com que o ator **Professor** herde as características de **Aluno**.

[image: Exemplo de diagrama de casos de uso usando generalização de atores]

Comment: Porém enquanto o sistema aumenta a herança vai dificultando na construção do software, na hora de modelar/re-modelar certo? Pois os alunos vão adquirindo novas funcionalidades no sistema e o professor "herda todas elas", ou eu entendi errado.

Comment: @RodrigoPires você está certo. Em outras situações pode generalizar como o LINQ descreveu, mas neste caso dizer que "todo Professor é também um Aluno" viola Liskov.

Comment: @Piovezan essa parte de herança poderia ser substituída com interfaces? Pois estabelecia um contrato entre as duas partes e seguir o contrato quando for necessário ou não.

Comment: @RodrigoPires Não tenho certeza, meu conhecimento de UML é fragmentado. Poderia ser por interface, mas quais seriam os nomes apropriados? Não consegui pensar em nenhum. Além disso interface sugere que teria que implementar o código na mão em vez de reaproveitá-lo (posso estar enganado). Acho que é um caso para "include" / "extend" (nunca lembro qual é qual) entre os casos de uso e não entre os atores.

Comment: De certa forma viola a segregação de interface também. Porque você deve ter um tipo que faz um monte de coisa não relacionada? Não diretamente mas na minha resposta eu falo disso. Fazer composição de capacidades é muito mais sensato que fazer um objetão que sabe fazer tudo