# Em POO classes de mesmo nível podem ter seus atributos e métodos herdados?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, herança

Em Java as classes de mesmo nível podem ser herdados os atributos?

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe `Usuario` e possuo duas classes filhas dessa classe. Uma se chama `Barbeiro` e a outra `Cliente`. Tem como eu herdar ou pegar de alguma forma os atributos e métodos do `Barbeiro` e vice-versa de alguma forma em Java?

[image: Diagrama das classes conforme descrito]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Comece lendo [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

É um pouco complicado responder o principal da pergunta porque não existe "mesmo nível" no mecanismo de herança. Você pode até conceitualmente interpretar assim, mas não tem como dizer isso no código sem alguma gambiarra sua.

Parece extremamente esquisito `Usuario` herdar de `Agenda`, uma coisa não tem nada com a outra, não poderia ter herança aí. Então se for para fazer errado você pode fazer qualquer coisa, eu vou responder sobre o certo. Para fazer certo precisa aprender todos conceitos fundamentais de computação, não basta decorar receita de bolo, elas não se aplicam em qualquer situação do mesmo jeito.

`Cliente` e `Barbeiro` herdarem de `Usuário` não parece fazer sentido. Poderia até fazer se eu tivesse mais detalhes, mas a minha experiência e conhecimento desse domínio me diz que não faz sentido. `Usuario` faz uma coisa, `Cliente` outra e `Barbeiro` outra. Inclusive pode ser mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo, e podem surgir novas classes, para isso é que existe herança, mas dos objetos certos.

Se isso é fixo e pode misturar tudo, então só precisa de `Usuario` e ali os dados necessários para o [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327842/101) de cliente e barbeiro que a pessoa exerça, é extremamente mais simples para algo que não precisará de extensão. E novamente, se precisar de extensão então tem que fazer certo para que ela possa ocorrer adequadamente. O pior que pode acontecer é adicionar complexidade (a herança) para ter ganho zero.

> Tem como eu herdar ou pegar de alguma forma os atributos e métodos do
> Barbeiro e vice-versa de alguma forma em Java?

Vice-versa com o que? Com `Cliente`? Não, se precisa disso está realmente errado e não deveria ter herança, precisa ter só `Usuario` com todo o necessário.

De preferência sem a herança de `Agenda` já que um `Usuario` não é uma `Agenda` por qualquer definição escolhida. A não ser que o nome da classe esteja completamente errado, mas é só o que eu sei sobre isso.

A não ser que você saiba de algo que eu não sei, ou isso também esteja errado, `MostrarAgenda()` no `Usuário`, se for pertinente existir isso, demonstra que `Agenda` deveria entrar por [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101) e não por herança.

A não ser que o objetivo seja outro não descrito na pergunta.