# Pedido e PedidoItem estabelecem uma composição?

Tags: uml, polimorfismo, composição, diagrama-de-classes, sobrescrita

Fiz a prova do concurso do IFSULDESTE de Minas Gerais organizada pela Fundação CEFET-MG e estou com dúvidas na seguinte questão:

17. Observe o diagrama de classes apresentado a seguir.

[image: Diagrama]

Sobre o diagrama, é INCORRETO afirmar que:

a) os métodos obterLimiteCredito definidos nas classes Fisica e Juridica são métodos sobrecarregados da classe Pessoa. 
b) na associação entre as classes Fisica e Juridica, as palavras “dirigente” e “diretor” representam o papel que cada uma das classes exerce nessa associação. 
c) a associação entre as classes Pedido e PedidoItem é uma composição. 
d) o método obterLimiteCredito da classe Pessoa não pode ser executado. 
e) na associação entre as classes Fisica e Juridica, a expressão “é administrada por” representa o nome da associação, e a seta, à esquerda da expressão, representa o sentido de leitura.

Fonte: Fundação CEFET. Disponível em: https://concurso.fundacaocefetminas.org.br/documentos/InformticaBomSucesso41637000719030930238.pdf. Acesso em: 31 jul 2019.

Marquei a letra A, pois entendo que há sobrescrita e não sobrecarga de métodos, nesse caso seria a única opção incorreta. No entanto, o gabarito preliminar aponta a letra C como a opção que responde a questão.

Por que seria a letra C a opção correta? A associação entre as classes `Pedido` e `PedidoItem` não é composição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há controvérsias quanto a letra A, por isso eu considero ela pelo menos dúbia. Ao mesmo tempo concursos costumam fornecer literatura para estudar que pode dizer o que está escrito ali e seria assim que deve responder, o que mostra que concurso não quer quem está habilitado e sim quem decora certas coisas. Eu considero essa opção errada, mas pode-se argumentar que não deixa de ser uma sobrecarga se considerar que são métodos com assinaturas diferentes, um parâmetro invisível, o `this` é diferente. Mas a sobrecarga normalmente se refere à assinatura visível. Mas como eu disse não é algo que tenha consenso. Pode-se dizer que ocorre as duas coisas.

E eu ficaria com ela porque a C me parece correta, pelo menos baseada na resposta que dei em [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). A composição é a forma de colocar dados relacionados de forma direta e que até poderia estar dentro do objeto principal  de tão acoplado que ele é, ou seja, você separa para melhor organização e quem sabe otimização (em algum aspecto), mas no fundo ele pertence ao objeto, sem esse objeto o objeto composto não pode existir, o que é exatamente o caso de itens de um pedido, ele só existe se o pedido existir, e só foi separado porque complica um pouco ter um número indeterminado de itens (tem solução em um banco de dados, e até na memória de forma bem atribulada, mas é melhor separar essa parte).

Talvez seja só uma confusão na interpretação do texto, mas se o texto dá essa margem não se a questão deveria ser válida. Um dos motivos é que associação e composição são antagônicas e a afirmação coloca como complementares, pode ser isso que a faz errada, seria uma pegadinha. Pode-se pedir uma argumentação porque essa "associação não é uma composição".

Portanto pegaria a Wikipedia e os *links* indicados ali, faria mais um pesquisa para confirmar mais e pediria anulação da questão, ainda que eles podem alegar que usaram uma literatura específica que diz o contrário, o que eu queria conhecer.

Answer (score 1):

## Representação gráfica de composição (UML)

Na especificação da UML, versão 2.5.1 ([aqui](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF)), e da qual foi extraída a imagem fornecida abaixo, a notação gráfica empregada para representar uma *composition* é exatamente aquela empregada de Pedido para PedidoItem (*black diamond* conforme a especificação citada da UML). Veja o exemplo fornecido na especificação na página 187.

Adicionalmente, nesta mesma especificação, o mesmo *black diamond* é a notação gráfica empregada para representar uma *composite aggregation*. Noutras palavras, na especificação, *composition* e *composite aggregation* são empregados para explicar o mesmo *black diamond*, embora o termo mais empregado seja *composite aggregation*.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, extraído da página 207 e, naturalmente, a legenda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fonte: [UML 2.5.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF)

Considerando a especificação da UML fornecida acima, em inglês, assim como a figura, o *black diamond* representa, sem dúvida, uma *composite aggregation* (até porque o termo *composition* é empregado poucas vezes e para explicar a *composite aggregation*). Ou seja, para sabermos se *composição* é o mesmo que *composite aggregation*, precisamos de uma referência em português devidamente aceita por ambas as partes.