# Normalização de banco de dados em sistema de RH

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de RH, nela vou ter muitos formulários em HTML que podem ou não ser muito extensos, a tabela de funcionários por exemplo tem 45 campos, alguns campos como empresa, função e local de trabalho são FKs para outras tabelas, porém ainda restam 42 campos que podem ser salvos nessa mesma tabela, alguns podem receber valores nulos.

Como posso padronizar alguns campos dessa tabela?

Uma observação é que ambos funcionários, empresas e local_atendimento possuem campos de endereço em comum, nesse caso eu poderia padronizar tudo em uma tabela de endereços?

Outra ideia seriam os documentos do funcionário, são mais 12 campos, seria ideal eu padronizar esses documentos em uma tabela especifica para isso?

Tabela de funcionários está dessa forma, ela possui 45 campos, vulgo tabelão
[image: Modelo]

Tabela modificada da pergunta original:

[image: Modelo "normalizado"]

Comment: E como vamos saber sem conhecer seu problema profundamente? Um dos erros que as pessoas cometem ao tentar modelar algo é achar que existem regras e receitas mágicas que você faz e fica certo. O certo depende do contexto. Você poderia fazer tudo isso e ficar bom ou ruim, e pode ter que fazer outras coisas, mas se a gente responder estaremos resolvendo o nosso problema ou um suposto problema, não o seu problema. Melhor depende. Tem coisas que dentro da normalidade parece errado e você nem tocou neles, ligados à normalização ou não, alguns daria para questionar.

Comment: Entendo, é que eu usei a modelagem somente para expressar a minha ideia, o banco de dados nem foi implementado ainda e esse modelo não representa o projeto final. Eu posso ter misturado as coisas colocando a modelagem que expressa minha ideia e não o problema em si, vou editar a pergunta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Em nível de modelagem conceitual você não deve se preocupar com a quantidade de atributos. Quando for transpor para o modelo físico você pode levar em conta se tais atributos podem ser separados em um conjunto dos mais comumente utilizados e outro conjunto dos raramente utilizados e então fisicamente criar duas tabelas com relacionamento 1:1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou responder de forma genérica, mas se atente ao comentário que fiz acima.

Eu estava escrevendo e a pergunta mudou ([a versão que eu respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/402810/1)), então a resposta pode parecer sem sentido. O modelo atual da pergunta parece fazer muito mais sentido e tem bem menos problemas.

Vi que a nova piorou algumas coisas. O número do endereço passou ser `int`, [isto é ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101). Mas os tamanhos parecem mais bem pensados, ou quase, por outro lado fica claro que algumas coisas não foram ou que deveria ser normalizados. Isto fica claro na coluna `estado` com 40 caracteres. Ainda é algo sem pensar porque o tamanho usado continua um número padronizado quase aleatório, porém menos esquisito. Todo estado, ou UF (unidade da federação como costuma ser o nome mais correto porque tem unidade que não é estado) deveria ter só 2 caracteres e basta isto ou então isto seria um código para a descrição, assim fica mais normalizado. Não que seja um completo absurdo fazer assim, mas em geral não é adequado.

Tem outros indícios que alguns tamanhos não estão muito adequados e lá vai gravar o que não deve, mas novamente, estou especulando sem saber o que é o real problema.

## Nomenclatura

Pra que usar `tab_` na frente dos nomes de tabelas? É uma informação óbvia. Pra que abreviar algumas colunas? Alguns não tenho ideia do que seja. Por que colocar parte do nome das colunas com algo óbvio? Não vou entrar no debate do que é óbvio ou não, por exemplo se nascimento não é sempre uma data e por isso essa informação é óbvia. Por que há inconsistência nos nomes? Nem vou entrar no mérito que as pessoas trabalham em entidades que não são empresas. Nem vou reclamar que, se entendi bem, a coluna `logradouro` armazenará o tipo do logradouro e não o logradouro em si.

Existe uma regra, que não precisa ser seguida sempre, que os nomes de campos que são sempre o mesmo ter sempre o mesmo nome, aí há uma controvérsia se um `id` deve ter o nome da tabela o prefixando ou não (eu não gosto de prefixar na tabela original porque gera uma informação redundante), mas deve prefixar onde ele é [chave estrangeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356021/101). Adote um padrão e siga.

## Tipagem

Carga horária deve ser um `char`?

Por que usou [`double` para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)?

Os tamanhos de alguns campos parecem quase aleatórios, parece que achou bonitinho fazer assim, modelagem segue um padrão que faça sentido, não é pra ser bonitinho.

Tem coisas que dá para questionar, não pode-se afirmar que está errado, mas será que um número do endereço deve ter 5 caracteres?

## Estrutura

Será que a ordem usada nas colunas ajudam a legibilidade? A chave estrangeira não é mais importante do que demonstra o diagrama?

Tem certeza que em algumas tabelas terão um `id` e outras terão um `cod`? [Entenda o que é uma chave natural antes de usá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101). [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101).

[Nem toda tabelas devem ter uma chave substituta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255270/101) ou mesmo [uma chave primária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390743/101), mas precisa ter um bom motivo para isto, e saber quais as consequências disto.

## [Normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101)

Se não vai ter chave primária clara, não terá um `id` próprio, será que esta tabela deveria existir? Não é um enorme problema ter uma [relação 1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101), mas quase sempre é desnecessário e ruim.

Qual a motivação de ter um endereço separado se esse endereço só pode pertencer a um funcionário? Se ele pudesse pertencer a mais de um funcionário, se o funcionário pudesse ter mais de um endereço ou se o endereço pudesse pertencer à outras tabelas, talvez fizesse sentido. Não vi justificativa, tudo que faz tem que justificar. Por que a empresa não teve o mesmo tratamento? Precisa ter o mesmo tratamento?

Na minha resposta sobre a pergunta de normalização eu falo sobre a canonicidade da informação e que a repetição não importa. Decidir se endereços devem estar em uma tabela separada passa por entender oque é isto. Só porque o endereço é o mesmo não quer dizer que seja a mesma informação. Assim como só porque existem dois `José da Silva` que são a mesma pessoa. Ou se dois irmãos gêmeos univitelinos sejam a mesma pessoa. Repetição não é o motivo para normalizar, ser canônico é.

Ou normaliza ou não. Essa tabela de dependente sofre do mesmo problema (normalizado demais) e consegue ao mesmo tempo estar normalizado de menos. Sempre tem 5 dependentes? Nem mais e nem menos? Se é assim então porque isto não está normalizado? Se não é para normalizar então pelo menos coloque na mesma tabela do funcionário. Hoje eu questiono mesmo se este tipo de dado deve ser normalizado. Tem um custo normalizar assim e tem um custo não normalizar, não é fácil decidir. Mas se não normalizar deve usar algum mecanismo do SGDB ou truque para simular uma normalização dentro da própria tabela, usando uma coluna *array*, JSON, ou uma `varchar` com um formato que permita colocar um número variável de entradas, [simulando assim um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118702/101). Isto pode dar uma simplificação e performance no modelo, mas terá que usar um recurso específico ou uma técnica própria para acessar esse dados (costuma ser melhor se souber fazer), você tem que pesar. Geralmente quando está [fazendo só uma composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400723/101) pode ser interessante internalizar na própria tabela. A normalização funciona melhor com associação ou agregação.

Pra piorar as colunas podem ser nulas, todas elas. [Um dos grandes motivos para normalizar é não precisar ter nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32182/101), e aí tem, ficou com o pior dos dois mundos.

Reforço para [repensar se não pode fazer as outras colunas não nulas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101). Em alguns casos deveria fazer a normalização ou usar o truque da composição citado antes. Só não tome como regra que não pode aceitar nulo, o nome da mãe e do pai realmente parece fazer sentido permitir nulo, por que senão terá que ter 3 tabelas, os funcionários que tem ambos pais conhecidos, os que tem só mãe, e os que tem só pai conhecido, e teria que fazer um `union` em todo `select`, fica horrível, ruim de modelar, e como a maioria dos RDBMS não possuem herança, ruim de dar manutenção, a regra mágica que alguns seguem pode trazer muito prejuízo. E é pior, por isso não gosto de lógica de negócios no DB, geralmente a regra aceita só a mãe e só o pai, mas tem que ter um deles, aí para ser certo precisaria ter uma `constraint` garantindo que seja um *OR*, e pra isso talvez terá que cria uma *stored procedure* ou uma função para usar na `constraint`, complicado, principalmente porque em alguns casos dependerá de um contexto que você não tem dentro do seu DB. Poderia ter usado o exemplo do estado civil que influencia o nome do cônjuge que tem regra condicional.

Será que não deveria ter normalização de escolaridade, naturalidade, etc.? Normalmente sim, é violação básica.

Tem certeza que documentos devem estar separados? Já leu sobre o problema de usar chave natural e se convenceu que CPF é péssimo como chave primária?

A pessoa não pode ter uma salário individualizado? Só tem o salário da função? Eu nem vou entrar no mérito que em casos reais esse modelo precisa ser absurdamente mais complicado que isso, essa é uma forma bem ingênua de ver como um departamento pessoal funciona e com o que ele tem que lidar, só estou neste item querendo dizer que a situação real deve definir como o modelo deve ser, se tentar adivinhar vai errar feio, mas se está criando um caso hipotético, esse caso só está na sua cabeça e só você pode resolvê-lo, não pode pedir ajudar de outras pessoas para isto.

Tem relações aí que eu não sei se estão certas, mas não posso afirmar sem conhecer o problema específico, pode ser que essa organização opere de uma forma pouco usual. Não sei a motivação da tabela `trabalho` e portanto não sei se ela deveria existir ou não e se deveria ser nesta forma.

## Conclusão

Isso foi olhando por cima, deve ter outros problemas.

Quantidade de colunas na tabela não indica nada se a modelagem está certa ou errada. As pessoas se apegam a detalhes que não importam e não olham para o que importa porque em geral as pessoas não entendem a função de se modelar algo.

Modelar dados é provavelmente a característica mais importante que um desenvolvedor deve ter, e a maioria, mesmo experientes, é bem ruim nisto. Tendo isso em mente comece se preparar. Precisa ter uma enorme capacidade de interpretação de texto, e um texto que sequer existe, e entendimento matemático, especialmente conjuntos, sabe aquilo que viu partindo da 3a. série (na minha época) e que quase ninguém dá bola e que muitos professores nem entendem porque estão ensinando aquilo? Se faltar essas coisas, comece tudo de novo, sem alicerce nada para em pé.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente a sua resposta bem completa, vou estar consultando a sua resposta outras vezes para ir aplicando no modelo, eu entendo que algumas coisas não tem tanta necessidade de ser seguido a risca, como o caso do estado, por ser uma aplicação pequena eu optei por receber o nome por completo mesmo, mas outras questões como usar decimal para valores, a explicação sobre chaves naturais e primarias achei bem útil quando estava estudando a disciplina tinha dúvidas sobre qual usar, a nomenclatura é porque geralmente utilizo views e por isso separo views e tab pelo nome, foi um costume adquirido.

Comment: No caso você sugeriu utilizar uma estrutura de Array ou JSON para os dependentes, no caso da minha aplicação um funcionário pode ter nenhum ou até 5 beneficiários e são armazenados somente nomes, por isso os campos são nulos, eu não tenho ideia de como fazer para trabalhar com um array ou JSON diretamente no campo de uma tabela, eu sei que quando eu envio um array para a tabela ele é armazenado como array, porém as informações não ficam visíveis, fica escrito somente 'array' no campo da tabela, enfim esse assunto vou ter que fazer algumas pesquisas e estudar para tentar fazer dessa forma

Comment: No caso do salário ele está vinculado a função, existem alguns outros valores que ficarão em outras tabelas e o salário será calculado usando esses valores e eu preciso ter esses valores separados por função. Enfim existem outros assuntos sim que eu não abordei na modelagem, esse modelo esta incompleto. Vou seguir as suas ideias gostei muito mesmo da sua explicação, mas não é um assunto que agente pega assim de repente, por isso estarei sempre relendo sua resposta, não farei mais comentários para não estender muito os comentários, não sei se é correto responder com vários comentários assim.