# Associação, agregação, etc. na prática?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, composição

Estou estudando POO e ainda não consigo ver, na prática, a diferença entre eles.

Basicamente tudo acaba em uma classe tendo como atributo a instância de outra classe. Porém se for `Departamento` e `Professor` seria agregação. Se for `Aluno` e `Professor` está mais pra associação.

O que difere é só na teoria e no conceito? Na prática é a mesma coisa?

Aqui está um exemplo prático que eu fiz:

```
    <?php
//Agregação
class Produto{
    public $nome;
    public $preco;
    function __construct($nome,$valor){
        $this->nome=$nome;
        $this->preco=$valor;
    }   
}


class Carrinho{
    public $produtos;
    public function add_produto(Produto $produto){
        $this->produtos[]=$produto;
    }
    public function print(){
        foreach ($this->produtos as $value ) {
                echo $value->nome;
        }
    }
}

$produto = new Produto("Teclado","50");
$produto2 = new Produto("Mouse","10");


$carrinho = new Carrinho();
$carrinho->add_produto($produto);
$carrinho->add_produto($produto2);

$carrinho->print();


?>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Na prática você deve aprender a teoria para compreender isto. As pessoas estão tão preocupadas com a prática que não entendem nada do que estão fazendo, só seguem receita de bolo.

A teoria foi passada em [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Lá tem um *link* para mais uma pergunta boa sobre o assunto. A teoria é muito clara sobre as diferenças entre eles, se tivesse estudado a teoria saberia disto.

No seu exemplo prático pode ser uma associação ou agregação, não há propriedade do objeto, mas eu não sei se há dependência do objeto principal com o secundário, pelo menos é o que dá para inferir por conhecimento universal, seu requisito poderia ser outro (esse é outro erro que as pessoas cometem na prática, aplicam a teoria, que muitas vezes ela nem entende bem sem olhar o contexto, o requisito prático).

O `Carrinho` não é dono do `Produto`, este último existe independente do primeiro, isto é fácil dizer, duvido que tenha um requisito que fale algo diferente. Mas não posso afirmar se há dependência dele, ou seja, se não tiver um produto no `Carrinho` o que acontece? Se o `Carrinho` não pode existir sem um `Produto` então é uma agregação, mas se ele pode continuar existindo mesmo sem um produto então é uma associação.

O seu código dá uma indicação que o `Carrinho` pode existir mesmo sem um `Produto` nele, afinal não usou um construtor que exige isto, mas o código está bem incompleto então não sei se dá para inferir alguma coisa por ele. Por exemplo, não tem uma forma de remover o produto e se valida que na última retirada de `Produto` o `Carrinho` deve ser apagado.

Sem a teoria e requisitos corretos não dá para fazer nada correto na prática. Programar não é fácil, modelar é bem difícil e isso é o que conta em desenvolvimento de software, e OOP exige mais ainda que faça certo, por isso algumas pessoas mais experientes e que não seguem receita de bolo evitam onde não cria valor muito grande no código.

Na prática aprendeu que [usa atributo, mas a teoria usa o termo campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Então está praticando errado.