# Relacionamentos entre classes na OO

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma classe `Hospedagem` e uma classe `NotaFiscal`, uma hospedagem tem uma nota fiscal e uma nota fiscal tem uma hospedagem.

Eu preciso colocar os atributos dentro das duas classes, o atributo `NotaFiscal` dentro de `Hospedagem` e o atributo `Hospedagem` dentro de `NotaFiscal`?

Outra dúvida é em um relacionamento 1 para muitos, por exemplo, um `Pedido` tem vários `ItemPedido` e um `ItemPedido` tem um `Pedido`, o pedido deve ter um atributo do tipo lista de `ItemPedido` e o pedido um atributo do tipo `Pedido`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) (eu sei, todo mundo aprendeu errado e ensina errado).

Se você tem essas duas classes relacionadas precisa ter uma forma de chegar na outra. Pelo menos um deles em uma direção tem que ter com certeza, caso contrário não há relacionamento. Se precisa do outro lado, depende. Eu não sei o que é essa tal `Hospedagem`. Quando você acessa uma hospedagem, precisa achar a nota fiscal relacionada de forma fácil? Então tem que ter esse campo em `Hospedagem`. Se você for acessar uma nota fiscal precisa saber de qual hospedagem ela se refere? Então precisa ter esse campo em `NotaFiscal`.

Depois com `Pedido` e `ItemPedido` é a mesma coisa. Sempre depende do que deseja. Como isso é algo mais conhecido é quase certo que tem alguma indicação sobre os itens na classe `Pedido`. Dependendo da solução pode ser alguma forma de lista em algum lugar, por isso é uma [agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).

A lista pode estar na classe `Pedido` e dentro da lista tem os `ItemPedido`, pelo menos tudo indica ser isso pela descrição fornecida. Existem outras formas de lidar com isso.

Ou outro jeito diferente seria `Pedido` ter só uma referência para uma classe `ItensPedido` (note o plural) e nela é que teria essa lista. Isso pode ser útil porque pode ter alguns campos relacionados a todos os itens. Não é tão comum, pode conceitualmente pode ser mais interessante (o conceitual as vezes se torna demais para o que precisa). Um desses campos poderia ser uma referência para o `Pedido`, se for necessário.

Mas olhando do jeito que está fazendo, se cada item deve ter uma referência para `Pedido` vai depender se pode acessar os itens individualmente de forma direta e precisa saber de a que pedido ele pertence.

Pode ajudar: [Associação, agregação, etc. na prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/418080/101).