# Classe associativa com dupla dependência

Tags: java, lista, classes, composição

Estava pesquisando na internet e vi esse modo de fazer associação entre classes Java. É correto fazer esse tipo de associação? Pois pesquisei muito na internet e não encontrei algo similar.

```
public class Aluno {
    private int codigo;
    private List<AlunoMateria> materias;
}

public class AlunoMateria {
    private Aluno aluno;
    private Materia materia;
    private Time horaAula;
}

public class Materia {
    private int codigo;
    private List<AlunoMateria> alunos;
}
```

Comment: O que pretende com a classe AlunoMateria? Se a classe Aluno tivesse uma `List<Materia>` e a classe Materia uma `List<Aluno>` não seria suficiente?

Comment: Só queria saber se isso é valido, pois no exemplo se coloca o tempo da horaAula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa coisa de certo ou errado é algo que as pessoas não entendem direito. Só existe certo dentro de um contexto. Não usou a palavra mas está querendo uma boa prática, que é uma praga porque desensina.

Isto parece errado porque não faz sentido um `Aluno` ter um monte de `AlunoMateria` (na forma como foi definida) ou uma `Materia` ter o mesmo. Parece misturar dois conceitos. Ou você tem a classe `AlunoMateria` que faz a amarração entre os dois e até teria uma lista delas. Ou não tem essa classe e a amarração é feita com listas em cada. Eu não gosto disto porque não ajuda nas relações, tem complicadores para atualizar (viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) de dados), mas vejo algumas pessoas fazendo. Aí você teria uma lista de `Materia`s no `Aluno` e uma lista de `Aluno`s na `Materia`.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). A forma que considero ideal é uma agregação, mas se fizer da outra forma é uma associação.

Por outro lado a necessidade pode indicar outra coisa.

Comment: No meu caso a Tabela AlunoMateria teria outros atributos que nem aluno e nem materia teriam.

Comment: Um dos motivos que eu acho a melhor solução, mas não manter listas dela nos dois outros objetos.

Comment: Você tá falando retirar  private List<AlunoMateria> alunos; Acho que não entendi.

Comment: Sim, conforme está explicado na resposta.

Comment: Há legal valeu.

Answer (score -1):

Depende.

Em termos simplesmente de implementação, até faz sentido porque você vai conseguir amarrar esta associação conforme esperado e necessário neste relacionamento *muitos-muitos*.

Considerando simplesmente conceitos de orientação a objetos, você poderia relacionar diretamente as classes sem a necessidade desta "classe para associação". O fato de parecer pouco fora da realidade um aluno carregar o nome da disciplina ou uma disciplina carregar o nome do aluno, você até justifica a necessidade desta 3a. entidade no seu sistema.

E desta forma, vale tanto como critérios de implementação ou conforme boa prática de projetos OO, a implementação da sua `AlunoMateria`,

**IMPORTANTE**: mas recomendo, que pra atender uma melhor apresentação OO e facilitar a legibilidade do seu código, a classe `AlunoMateria` poderia muito se chamar `Matricula`, ficando muito mais adequado ao seu propósito e permitindo ainda mais legibilidade OO do seu modelo.