# O que é Aggregate no MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Eu sei que esse tipo de duvida eu acho "facilmente" na própria documentação e na internet, entretanto mesmo na documentação oficial ficou muito confuso e muito técnico com vários termos desconhecidos.

Enfim, estou precisando de ajuda para entender o conceito teórico de **Aggregate**. Eu já pesquisei até entendi um pouco o funcionamento, mas quando me perguntam o que é... não faço nem ideia de como responder.

Atualmente eu responderia assim:

"*Aggregate é um método do MongoDB que recebe um array com vários objetos. Esses objetos têm chaves específicas que fazem o aggregate executar ações que operam os dados desse schema como filtro de dados, contagem de valores repetidos, soma, agrupamento e etc.*"

Só que tudo pareceu perdido quando um amigo meu falou que minha resposta não tinha nada haver. Agora parece que tudo que estudei e pesquisei não faz sentido.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101

Comment: esse link não tem nada relacionado a aggregate da pergunta. O link é sobre conceitos de modelagem OOP, a agregação da pergunta está relacionada a agregar informação e não modelo, como um `group by` de query SQL, ou fazer um `map/reduce` dos dados

Comment: Se não tem nada a ver eu aconselharia as pessoas não usarem o que tem um nome de algo que não é o que diz ser: `estou precisando de ajuda para entender o conceito teórico de Aggregate` e que nada tem a ver com OOP conforme a resposta linkada, é um conceito universal da computação.

Comment: quanto ao nome me parece certo, é o nome da funcionalidade no próprio `mongodb`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/  assim como no `sql-sever`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql  só os conceitos são diferentes, aqui a nível de informação, no OOP, a nível de modelagem

Comment: _"só os conceitos são diferentes, aqui a nível de informação, no OOP, a nível de modelagem"_ Isso não é conceito diferente, é aplicação do mesmo conceito em contextos diferentes.

Comment: desculpa @Bacco, mesmo sabendo que não vou conseguir convencer vcs, vou defender meu ponto. Agregação em OOP é um conceito de modelagem onde um objeto faz parte do outro. A agregação nos dados, que é o que tem na pergunta, são operações de calculo, agrupamento e transformação de dados, que não exige que haja dois objetos envolvidos, e mais, se houver, os objetos não precisam fazer parte um do outro, essa é a diferença. Um "distinct" é uma operação de agregação, que nada tem a ver com a agregação OOP, é feita numa única coluna, não envolve 2 objetos, entende? Por isso são conceitos diferentes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os conceitos de agregação (entre outros conceitos de modelagem) tem no link que o @Maniero já comentou: [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86715/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-oop)

As operações de agregação no `mongodb` são operações que agrupam os dados e retornam resultados computados, como somas e contagem por exemplo.

> Aggregation operations process data records and return computed results. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.

Da documentação aqui: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Em tradução livre:

> As operações de agregação processam registros de dados e retornam
> resultados computados. As operações de agregação agrupam valores de
> vários documentos e podem executar uma variedade de operações nos
> dados agrupados para retornar um único resultado.

É semelhante ao conceito de `GROUP BY` de um banco de dados relacional.

Em exemplo de agregação, contando elementos seria por exemplo, a partir de uma fonte de dados assim:

```
[
  {
    "nome": "João",
    "estado": "RJ",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Maria",
    "estado": "RJ",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "João",
    "estado": "SP",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Maria",
    "estado": "SP",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "João",
    "estado": "PB",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Maria",
    "estado": "PB",
    "pais": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "nome": "John",
    "estado": "CA",
    "pais": "USA"
  }
]
```

Se quiser agregar os valores dos estados e contar o número de ocorrências em cada estado, poderia escrever uma operação assim:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$estado",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Ou seja, uma operação de "group", pela propriedade "estado", executando "count", somando 1 para cada ocorrência. O resultado dessa operação de agregação será:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "RJ",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "SP",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "PB",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "CA",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Pode ser visto em execução aqui: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TFE7xvjRGbz

Todas as operações e comandos de agregação podem ser consultados na documentação: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/interface/

Answer (score -4):

Eu não sou nenhum especialista mas já usei aggregate para otimizar o processamento e a performance das consultas da minha aplicação.

O aggregate permite que voce passe para o próprio mongo os parametros que deseja, evitando que o processamento fique a encargo da sua aplicação backend.

Ex: imagine que tu queira buscar do seu banco todos os pedidos de um cliente.

pra resolver esse problema da forma convencional, você precisaria carregar o cliente e também todos os pedidos, depois processar cada um deles comparando se o id do cliente está presente dentro do ref do pedido.

com aggregate, e com a fórmula correta você pode poupar esse processamento por parte do seu back, e informar para o próprio mongo executar um $match.

[Info](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/MongoDB-Aggregation#:%7E:text=O%20Aggregation%20do%20MongoDB%20trabalha,daquela%20posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20existem%20na%20empresa.)