# O construtor base SEMPRE é executado quando o derivado é chamado?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

O construtor base SEMPRE é executado quando o derivado é chamado? Minha dúvida é mais focada no `:base`.

No exemplo abaixo, quando instanciamos um objeto do tipo `Teste`, o `Reservation` também é instanciado?

O que me deixa mais confuso é que eu vi que o `:base` serve para chamar um método ou um construtor da classe base, mas em um vídeo de um professor eu vi ele comentando diferente.

Então, para mim, acredito que se estamos utilizando o `:base` na classe derivada para chamar um construtor da classe base vão ser executados os construtores de ambas as classes, assim instanciando dois objetos, não?

[image: código exemplificando]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O construtor base SEMPRE é executado quando o derivado é chamado?

Não, só quando deixa o compilador fazer automaticamente, normalmente acontece no construtor padrão, mas não nos demais. É quase certo que deveria chamar manualmente em todos os casos que o compilador não faça.

> quando instanciamos um objeto do tipo `Teste`, o `Reservation` também é instanciado?

Não exatamente. Só um objeto é instanciado, por isso há herança, se tivesse que instanciar outro objeto seria a [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Só um objeto do tipo `teste` é criado. Ele existe com suas características e as herdadas de `Reservation`.

Herança é assumir o DNA de outra classe, ou seja, fazer com que os objetos da classe derivada tenham tudo o que a classe base tem e provavelmente mais alguma coisa (podem ser mudanças, mas não retirada, de alguns detalhes). Pense nela, grosso modo, como um <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> do que tem na classe base para a derivada.

Quando você cria um construtor na classe derivada você pode inicializar o objeto instanciado do jeito que achar que é necessário para cumprir o objetivo dele. Em tese não tem que chamar o construtor base, porém é quase certo que deveria fazê-lo. Como vai inicializar as partes do objeto que são definidos na classe base? Você pode fazer ali no construtor derivado, afinal tudo que tem na base tem na derivada, tem casos que isso pode ser útil. Porém na maioria dos casos o certo é deixar o construtor base fazer o que ele sabe fazer bem, inclusive porque se ele mudar essa mudança se refletirá na classe derivada automaticamente, essa é toda ideia da herança.

Não só construtor, mas tudo o que puder fazer algo mais e depois delegar para o que a base já sabe fazer, tende ser mais correto. Boa parte das heranças de métodos em uma classe ou deixa como está ou faz algo chamando o método base também.

Essa sintaxe de `base()` serve para garantir a chamada de forma destacada e antes de qualquer outra execução do método, não corre o risco de colocar no meio do corpo do método em local errado. Nada impede de chamar a base dentro do corpo do método, mas não costuma ser tão adequado.

A sua confusão é porque acha que o construtor cria um novo objeto quando na verdade ele mais inicializa o objeto já existente. Como já disse antes, está aprendendo por referências ruins. O que mais tem na internet é informação errada sobre tudo.

Então usando o exemplo, quando manda instanciar o objeto (`new Teste(...)` eu colocaria o exemplo todo se a pergunta tivesse colocado o código em texto e não como imagem que é algo inadequado, inclusive prejudicando quem precisa de um leitor por ter deficiência visual) acontecem duas coisas:

1. Cria o objeto fazendo a alocação de memória e reserva do espaço que caiba todo estado do objeto.
2. Chama o construtor que é apenas um método estático da classe.

Como podemos ver no código este método chama outro método existente na classe `Reservation`. Esse último método atribui um valor em duas propriedades (`Name` e `Idade` essas misturebas ajuda ir confundindo mais a compreensão de tudo, a herança toda não faz sentido, ajuda aprender o mecanismo e aprender errado o conceito) usando os parâmetros recebidos. Note que essas propriedades estão em `Teste`, o único objeto existente nessa instanciação, já que elas foram herdadas de `Reservation`.

Quando esse método base termina de executar, ele executa o método que foi chamado inicialmente na instanciação e ele atribui o outro parâmetro recebido para a propriedade que só existe em `Teste`.

[Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Comment: "Como podemos ver no código este método chama outro método existente na classe Reservation. Esse último método atribui um valor em duas propriedades (Name e Idade essas misturebas ajuda ir confundindo mais a compreensão de tudo, a herança toda não faz sentido, ajuda aprender o mecanismo e aprender errado o conceito) usando os parâmetros recebidos. Note que essas propriedades estão em Teste, o único objeto existente nessa instanciação, já que elas foram herdadas de Reservation." ...

Comment: Continuando:
Acho que consegui entender, a chamada do construtor da classe base utilizando o :base na classe derivada, atribui valores para as propriedades Name e Idade do objeto da derivada(Mas por meio do construtor da classe base), é isso?

Comment: È isso mesmo...