# Relação de agregação e atributo das classes

Tags: java, classes, uml

A agregação só ocorre quando uma classe `A,` que agrega uma classe `B`, tem um atributo do tipo `B`?

Pode haver agregação sem, necessariamente, uma classe ter um atributo do tipo da outra?

Por exemplo, se eu instancio um objeto de outra classe em um método da minha classe, mas esse objeto instanciado não é atributo da minha classe, a relação ainda é de composição?

Comment: Aqui há uma boa explicaçãõ e não apenas de agregação https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25619/composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-e-como-usar

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Depende do ponto de vista, mas em geral a agregação num modelo de classes ocorre apenas quando há um atributo.

## Estrutura de classes

Em geral, quando falamos em diagramas de classes, estamos nos referindo à **estrutura** delas. Portanto, a agregação somente ocorreria no caso de `A` ter um atributo do tipo `B`.

Não estamos preocupados com detalhes de implementação enquanto estamos modelando ou fazendo um projeto em alto nível do sistema.

## Análise estática do código

Por outro lado, se fizermos uma **análise estática do código** de uma classe pronta para determinar dependências, podemos encontrá-las:

- **Explícitas ou diretas**: em tipos de variáveis e parâmetros, por exemplo. Geralmente vai haver um `import` para cada referência.
- **Implícitas ou indiretas**: ao usar uma interface sem saber a implementação ou quando há encadeamento de chamadas, tal como em `objetoB.getObjetoC().getAtributo()`, pois nesse caso dependemos de `C` sem que haja uma ligação direta com a classe em `A`.

## Análise dinâmica em execução

Indo mais a fundo, podemos ainda fazer uma **análise em tempo de execução** para determinar as dependências reais que uma classe precisa para executar.

Considera-se aqui que algumas das implementações de interfaces podem ser providas:

- Em tempo de execução, por exemplo através de plugins ou por bibliotecas que não estão presentes durante a compilação
- Pelo uso de reflexão, instanciando ou acessando classes pelo nome delas
- De acordo com a entrada do usuário ou configuração do programa, onde os tipos de instâncias podem variar
- Por bibliotecas que geram classes dinamicamente

## Considerações

A modelagem estrutural das classes é boa para se pensar no domínio do sistema, mas não garante e nem deve tentar garantir a forma alguma como o sistema executa nem suas dependências em tempo de execução.

A análise estática do código ajuda a determinar o acoplamento e coesão de uma classe, de forma que deve-se sempre tentar diminuir a quantidade de dependências.

Por fim, a análise em tempo de execução é a única que dá total garantia do que realmente está sendo executado, mas também é a mais custosa e complexa. Ainda, ela é dependente do momento, o que significa que o comportamento do sistema varia ao longo do tempo de uso e algumas vezes é bem difícil reproduzir o cenário desejado.