# Qual o nome do conceito empregado nesse código?

Tags: java, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, composição

Se eu criar por exemplo duas classes e colocar a classe `Funcionario` com uma variável `Empregado` na classe `Empresa`, qual o significado disso e para que serve?

```
class Funcionario {
    String nome;
    String cpf;
}

class Empresa {
   String nome;
   Funcionario empregado; 
}
```

Comment: Isso se chama [composição](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-conceito-de-heranca-e-composicao/25456).

Comment: Para que serve a composição?

Comment: No link tem uma explicação bem tranquila a respeito, vê se ele te esclarece.

Comment: Talvez relevante: [Composição e agregação: quais as diferenças e como usar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25619/3117)

Comment: Não sei bem onde está sua dúvida, mas no nível mais básico, `Funcionario` é o tipo do membro `empregado` esperado nas instâncias de `Empresa`.

Comment: @ThiagoDeBonis a resposta te ajudou? Sabe que pode aceitar uma resposta em suas perguntas, né? Algo precisa ser melhorado para que a resposta seja aceita?

Answer (score 6):

Isso parece ser uma [**associação**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101) (precisaria de mais detalhes para ter certeza, estou usando a intuição). Eventualmente poderia ser uma **composição** (novamente, depende de detalhes). E um dia pode querer mudar para uma **agregação**, afinal a empresa deve ter vários funcionários.

Answer (score 6):

Nesse exemplo, de fato, não dá pra saber se é uma associação ou composição. Precisaria saber se esse objeto Funcionario é instanciado dentro da classe Empresa ou não.

Na composição:

- o ciclo de vida de um objeto (Funcionario) é dependente do ciclo de vida de outro (Empresa), então a criação da instância Funcionario acontece dentro da classe Empresa.

Na associação:

- o ciclo de vida de um objeto não é dependente do outro (geralmente essa relação de dá por métodos, um método do Empresa tem como parâmetro um Funcionario)