# Não lembro alguns conceitos sobre arrays de classes

Tags: java, array, classes

Estou querendo saber.

1 - O meu raciocínio está correto? Por exemplo, se eu colocar `Funcionário funcionario` dentro da classe `Empresa`, quer dizer que: "Na empresa tem funcionário". Correto?

2 - Como eu faço para definir um array de classe, ou seja, eu quero definir quantos clientes podem ter no banco, quantos cartões pode ter para cada cliente.

```
Rgn.java
class Banco {
    static String nome = "Banco Saad";
    static String cnpj = "000.000.000";

    Cliente clientes;
    Conta contas;
    Cartoes cartoes;
}

class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;

    Cartoes cartoes;

    Cliente(String nome,String cpf){
        this.nome = this.nome;
        this.cpf = this.cpf;
    }

    }

    public String getCliente(){
        return this.nome;

    }
}


class Conta {
    private String agencia;
    private String conta;
    private double saldo;

    Cartoes cartoes;

    Conta(String agencia, String conta){
        this.agencia = this.agencia;
        this.conta = this.conta;
    }
}

class Cartoes {
    private String nomeCliente;
    private String tipoStats[] = {"Fit", "Diamond"};
    private String tipoCartao[] = {"Débito", "Crédito"};
    private String tipoLocal[] = {"Nacional", "Internacional"};
    private String bandeiraCartao = "Mastercard";
    private String numeroCartao;
    private double limiteCartao;

    Conta contas;

    Cartoes (String nomeCliente, String numeroCartao, double limiteCartao){
        this.nomeCliente = this.nomeCliente;
        this.numeroCartao = this.numeroCartao;
        this.limiteCartao = this.limiteCartao;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual o nome do conceito empregado nesse código?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141340/qual-o-nome-do-conceito-empregado-nesse-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: [Help here! cURL webservice PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141417/45854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, deixe o nome das classes no singular. Portanto "`Cartoes`" deveria ser trocada por "`Cartao`".

Segundo, não se esqueça do modificador `private` ou `public` caso você não esteja interessado em visibilidade de pacote (raramente é o caso).

Terceiro, há um `}` a mais sobrando no meio da classe `Cliente`.

Quarto, se você quiser definir arrays, pode fazer assim:

```
class Banco {
    private static String nome = "Banco Saad";
    private static String cnpj = "000.000.000";

    private Cliente[] clientes;
    private Conta[] contas;
    private Cartao[] cartoes;
}
```

O array tem um tamanho fixo e definido. Você pode criá-lo assim:

```
clientes = new Cliente[50];
```

E isso vai criar um array com 50 posições. Inicialmente todas elas estarão vazias (contendo `null`).

Para colocar um elemento no array:

```
 Cliente fulano = ...;
 clientes[10] = fulano;
```

Ou para colocar vários:

```
 Cliente fulano = ...;
 clientes[10] = fulano;
 Cliente ciclano = ...;
 clientes[11] = fulano;
 Cliente beltrano = ...;
 clientes[12] = beltrano;
```

Para obter o tamanho do array (no número total de posições, e não em número de posições utilizadas):

```
 int tamanho = clientes.length;
```

No entanto, rapidamente você vai perceber que arrays são um tanto baixo nível demais e usá-los é um tanto trabalhoso e difícil. Para inserir elementos, você terá que rastrear em qual posição ele vai ser inserido. Para excluir elementos  do meio (colocando um `null` em alguma posição), um buraco ficará no array e você terá que se virar para arrumar isso. Se o tamanho do array for pequeno demais, não vai caber e daí você terá que criar um outro array maior, copiar todos os elementos e usar esse novo array para substituir o original. Além de outras dificuldades.

Assim sendo, talvez você queira usar [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), que é muito mais fácil e prático de se usar do que arrays:

```
class Banco {
    private static String nome = "Banco Saad";
    private static String cnpj = "000.000.000";

    private List<Cliente> clientes;
    private List<Conta> contas;
    private List<Cartao> cartoes;
}
```

Você pode notar que `List` é uma interface. Há algumas implementações, tais como [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ou [`java.util.LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), além de algumas outras para finalidades mais específicas.

Por exemplo, vamos criar uma lista de clientes:

```
 clientes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Observe que você não precisa especificar o tamanho. O `ArrayList` ajusta o seu próprio tamanho interno automaticamente quando necessário. Se você especificar o tamanho mesmo assim (ex: `ArrayList<>(20)`), ao inserir um elemento que estoure o tamanho, ele altera o seu próprio tamanho interno sem problemas (isso pode ter algum custo de desempenho, mas funciona mesmo assim).

Para acrescentar elementos no `List`:

```
 Cliente fulano = ...;
 clientes.add(fulano);
```

Ou então para adicionar vários clientes de uma vez:

```
 Cliente fulano = ...;
 clientes.add(fulano);

 Cliente ciclano = ...;
 clientes.add(ciclano);

 Cliente beltrano = ...;
 clientes.add(beltrano);
```

E ele já é adicionado automaticamente no final, você não precisa ficar controlando qual é a posição adequada a se fazer isso. Para obter o tamanho (com `cliente.size()`) ele te dá o número de elementos inseridos e não o número de posições internas disponíveis, o que é uma informação muito mais útil na prática. Além disso, ao remover um elemento do meio, ele automaticamente já elimina o buraco que ficaria.

Para limitar o número de elementos, basta usar um `if`. Por exemplo:

```
public class Cliente {

    private List<Cartao> cartoes;

    // ...

    public void adicionarCartao(Cartao paraAdicionar) {
        if (cartoes.size >= maximoCartao) throw new IllegalStateException("Este cliente já tem cartões demais.");
        cartoes.add(paraAdicionar);
    }
}
```

Por fim, ao vermos este código:

```
class Banco {
    private static String nome = "Banco Saad";
    private static String cnpj = "000.000.000";

    private List<Cliente> clientes;
    private List<Conta> contas;
    private List<Cartao> cartoes;
}
```

Podemos interpretar como:

- Cada banco tem uma lista de clientes.
- Cada banco tem uma lista de contas.
- Cada banco tem uma lista de cartões.
- Todos os bancos compartilham um nome em comum (não acho que seja o que você quer, mas é o que esse código diz).
- Todos os bancos compartilham um CNPJ em comum (novamente, não acho que seja o que você quer, mas é o que esse código diz).

Comment: muito obrigado.. No caso irei criar só com ArrayList agora e sem vetores.. Mais olha só você disse que para adicionar é só utilizar : 

 Cliente fulano = ...;
 clientes.add(fulano);

Porem se eu quiser adicionar mais de um cliente, oque eu devo fazer com essa "variavel" fulano? 

Na parte do static no banco eu quiz disser que seria só um banco, e todos os Clientes,Cartoes etc ficariam com o cnpj e nome desse banco.

Comment: Tinha encaminhado errado o comentário, já ajustei acima.

Comment: @ThiagoDeBonis Editado. O que acha?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Está correto, tudo no código (exceto um erro sintático), no conceito de um modo geral, pelo menos até onde dá para identificar. Claro que em código real muita coisa está errada aí. Por isso é complicado tentar aprender conceitos com simulações de problemas, em coisa inventada tudo pode ser certo. Em problema real depende da especificação e provavelmente seriam bem diferente do que foi modelado aí. Problemas "inventados" podem ser úteis para ajudar em pontos específicos de codificação, não para arquiteturar um sistema.

2 - Pode fazer igual que já foi feito em cartões:

```
Cliente[] clientes = new Cliente[50]; //para 50 clientes
```

Se quiser que não tenha um limite específico use uma lista:

```
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>(); //inicializando p/ evitar exceção
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Declaration.java).

É claro que tem várias outras coisas que precisam ser melhoradas nas classes.

Comment: Oi @bigown, poderia citar o que devo melhorar? estou estudando pelo Alura e só estou querendo ver o que tenho que rever para poder avançar no curso. Eu não tenho experiência nenhuma em "sistema real" pois estou na faculdade ainda, estou pegando certificado no Alura de Desenvolvedor Java Junior para ver se consigo um estágio.

Comment: Na verdade não, a lista é enorme, está muito longe de ser algo adequado, a pergunta ficaria ampla e teria que ser fechada para responder tudo. Outro problema é que para melhorar precisa ter um problema mais específico. Em algo inventado, qualquer coisa pode servir. Você pode falar "era assim que eu queri", pronto está certo. A maioria desses cursos não ensinam bem. Tem que dar um passo de cada vez. Não adianta tentar aprender arquitetura, modelagem sem dominar bem a linguagem. Primeiro aprender programar o básico nota 10, depois pensar em juntar tudo.

Comment: Mas está num caminho melhor que muita gente que só segue receita de bolo. Vai fazendo perguntas bem específicas e vai melhorando cada ponto.

Comment: Entendi @bigown, como você disse.. Você usuou "ArrayList" que no caso eu não aprendi ainda, mais eu poderia fazer Cliente[] clientes = new Cliente[]; Para gravar "infinitamente" ? Você acha que esses cursos do Alura vale apena para conseguir estágio na área de programação? Pois aqui no RJ está bem complicado conseguir estágio e eu não quero enviar para emprego, pois estou realmente com medo de já começar empregado sem ter experiência de estágio. rs

Comment: Não pode, *array* tem tamanho fixo. Não sei o que vale, eu sei que eu não contrataria alguém que aprendeu exclusivamente por este tipo de curso. Mas o mercado aceita tanta coisa, sei lá. Eu gosto das coisas certas. Até existe um crise que complica um pouco as coisas, mas se no Rio estiver ruim, então só em SP estará bom. O que não acho que seja verdade. Tem casos que não tem vaga mesmo, mas muito caso é porque a pessoa ainda não está preparada. Não procure estágio como um favor que vão te fazer, torne sua contratação desejável que abrirão vagas até onde não tem.