# Adicionar vários índices de um vetor como parâmetro

Tags: java, array

Estou iniciando em JAVA. Criei duas classes, a classe `Pessoa`, que recebe os seguintes parâmetros na instanciação de um novo objeto:

```
public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, char sexo)
```

E a classe `Livro`:

```
public Livro(String titulo, String autor, int totPaginas, Pessoa leitor)
```

E na classe principal, fiz as seguintes instanciações:

```
Pessoa[] p = new Pessoa[2];
Livro [] l = new Livro[3];

p[0] = new Pessoa("Pedro" , 22 , 'M');
p[1] = new Pessoa("Maria" , 25 , 'F');

l[0] = new Livro("Aprendendo JAVA" , "José da Silva"    , 400 , p[0]);
l[1] = new Livro("POO em JAVA"     , "Márcio Bezerra"   , 500 , p[1]);
l[2] = new Livro("JAVA avançado"   , "Fernanda Pereira" , 900 , p[0]);
```

Como adicionar vários índices do vetor `Pessoa []` como parâmetro na instanciação de um novo objeto livro, ou seja, como fazer, por exemplo, Pedro **E** Maria lerem o livro "POO em JAVA", sem ter que instanciar outro livro idêntico?

Comment: Creio que a lógica está invetida. Pra mim não faz sentido adicionar "Pessoa" em Livro apenas para marcar que ela já o leu. Talvez o inverso faça bem mais sentid e dê menos trabalho.

Comment: @diegofm você tem razão, mas o problema do AP vai se manter, quando uma pessoa ler mais de um livro.

Comment: @ramaral não se Livro deixar de ser um parametro de existencia de um objeto pessoa e criar-se uma lista(num exemplo mais rudimentar possivel) na classe pessoa onde se armazenaria os livros lidos.

Comment: @diegofm O que eu quis dizer foi que mudar a lógica não resolvia o problema, era preciso algo mais e sim a solução é essa: criar uma lista que, apesar de não ser tão "lógico", pode também ser feita no objecto Livro.

Answer (score 2):

## A relação precisa ser `Um para Muitos`

Para ter essa relação você precisa que a classe `Livro` tenha, internamente, uma Lista de `Pessoa`. Para fazer isso você pode criar um método em `Livro` com o nome `adicionarPessoa`, por exemplo, e depois que instanciar o objeto `Livro`, poderá adicionar as pessoas.

```
l[0] = new Livro("Aprendendo JAVA" , "José da Silva"    , 400);
l[0].adicionarPessoa(p[0]);
l[0].adicionarPessoa(p[1]);

l[1] = new Livro("POO em JAVA"     , "Márcio Bezerra"   , 500);
l[1].adicionarPessoa(p[0]);
```

Tem uma questão sobre [Composição e Agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25619/composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-e-como-usar) aqui no SOpt que pode te ajudar a entender essas relações.