# Serealizar uma JSON String C#

Tags: c#, json

Queria montar uma JSON String, porém não consigo criar a classe da forma que preciso, consigo pegar informações até o primeiro nível, mas não consigo criar subchaves.

Por exemplo eu quero que a string seja

```
{
  "nome": "Nome",   
  "familia": {
    "pai": "Nome do PAI",
    "mae": "Nome da MÃE"
   },
  "contato": {
    "celular": "Numero do celular",
    "casa": "Numero da casa"
   }
}
```

Minha tentativa:

```
public class Pessoa
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }

        class Familia
        {
            public string pai { get; set; }
            public string mae { get; set; }
        }

        class Contato
        {
            public string celular { get; set; }
            public string casa { get; set; }
        }
        //Essa classe está correta ?
    }

private void btnSerealiza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa
        {

            nome = "Nome",
            //Como ficaria aqui ?
        };

        tbRetorno.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

Sou novato nisso então toda ajuda ou critica será bem vinda.

Comment: No caso você quer saber como preencher os subobjetos de Pessoa no clique do botão?

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso transformar a class pessoa em uma string JSON, mas não estava conseguindo criar subchaves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar as classes separadas, e dentro da classe `Pessoa` você terá um objeto da classe `Familia`:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public Familia familia {get;set;}
    public Contato contato {get;set;}

}

public class Familia
{
    public string pai { get; set; }
    public string mae { get; set; }
}

public class Contato
{
    public string celular { get; set; }
    public string casa { get; set; }
}
```

> Quando há objetos dentro de outros, chamamos de agregação ou composição.

---

> Utilizando:

```
private void btnSerealiza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa
    {
        nome = "Nome",
        familia = new Familia()
        {
            pai = "nome do pai",
            mae = "nome da mae"
        },
        contato = new Contato()
        {
            celular = "123132123",
            casa = "156448"
        }
    };

    tbRetorno.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25628/69359

http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/oop_cph1.htm

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, todos os artigos que vi me deram uma ideia mas não estava conseguindo fazer, obrigado pela ajuda.