# Qual a diferença entre OO e DDD?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, ddd

Li sobre Domain Driven Design, parece utilizar os conceitos de orientação a objetos porém se baseia mais nas regras de negócio. Não há nada além disso que diferencie de fato OO de DDD? Se for possível exemplificar como é feito esse reforço das regras de negócio em comparação com OO.

Comment: DDD tem seus próprios conceitos e design patterns os quais, a rigor, são independentes do paradigma da orientação a objetos. Sugiro uma lida nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40962/14584

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Na verdade há diferenças entre OO e DDD, mas ambos se encaixam. Explicando rapidamente:

- OO é um paradigma de programação e modelagem cujo propósito é realizar uma abstração do funcionamento do "mundo real" para sistemas computacionais. Ou seja, utiliza-se de classes, objetos, métodos, etc. para simular uma interação entre elementos do mundo real em um computador de forma mais natural.
- DDD é uma abordagem para desenvolvimento de softwares onde o há um grande foco no domínio. Para que se possa desenvolver um software para um domínio específico deve-se utilizar uma linguagem OO, pois ela é perfeita para representar e abstraír o domínio estudado em um sistema computacional.

Answer (score 10):

Resolvi responder porque ando estudando muito o assunto e quase tudo o que se escreve sobre ele recentemente não me convence. Acho boa parte do que se divulga sobre DDD ou mesmo OO tem falhas ou são insustentáveis.

Não gosto dessa ideia de OO querer representar o mundo real. Eu sei que sempre venderam essa ideia, mas ela é falha e induz a aprender e fazer coisas erradas neste paradigma. Nós não conseguimos reproduzir o mundo real, ele é complexo demais para fazer isto. E é uma pena que exemplos de códigos orientados a objeto tentem fazer exatamente isto ensinando as pessoas fazerem herança onde não cabe. Já notou que a maioria dos exemplos são relacionados com biologia, e que quase nenhum problema no seu código é de biologia? Em biologia é fácil fazer herança, desde que você ignore quase tudo o que acontece de fato ali.

Em geral OO é bom para construir mecanismos já abstratos e em alguns casos simular objetos concretos em uma forma abstrata muito simplificada. Então usar OO em GUI ou jogos ou outros mecanismos que só existem no computador é muito bom, mas para modelar o tal do mundo real precisamos fazer adaptações.

Um exemplo é uma classe `Pessoa`, não podemos representar uma pessoa de fato ali (ela é complexa demais para reproduzi-la em uma classe), podemos fazer uma abstração do que é importante para nosso problema sobre uma pessoa, só isto. Então podemos ter campos e métodos nesta classe para dar o que precisamos. E por esse erro de conceituação as pessoas acham que um `Cliente` é uma `Pessoa` e fazem herança, quando não é, mas o cliente é uma abstração de uma relação (algo já abstrato), provavelmente comercial, que uma pessoa tem com uma instituição ou mecanismo, por isso sequer tem relação de herança como todo mundo faz, e as pessoas o fazem porque aprenderam com os exemplos ruins de OO.

Não é só questão de simular o objeto real, é fazer uma interpretação desse objeto e do seu papel **no seu sistema**, e isto não é fácil em domínios de negócios, um dos motivos que eu critico um pouco o uso extensivo de OOP para este tipo de aplicação (nada contra fazer para os mecanismos da aplicação, mas complica um pouco fazer o mesmo com as regras de negócio, e para fazer certo tende a complicar muito a aplicação, e ainda para fazer certo é preciso ter um domínio muito grande do domínio (não podia perder de fazer essa :), o que quase ninguém tem).

E sou um crítico maior ainda de DDD principalmente pelo que acabei de dizer. Não digo que ele nunca deva ser usado, mas nunca vi dando certo, com provas disto. Ele é ótimo no papel, quando é um sonho, mas a prática se mostra muito mais complicada. E nem digo que não aprendemos boas lições estudando o assunto e que não podemos aplicar algumas coisas da metodologia.

É verdade que DDD usa técnicas de OOP, mas ao mesmo tempo algumas coisas que ele prega são um pouco contra o que OOP deve ser (o que pode ser até bom, nem coloco isto como crítica, OOP não é essa panaceia que quase todo mundo tem certeza que é, mesmo as vezes fazendo discurso que não é). Na verdade esta disciplina melhora algumas coisas, mas incentiva outras bastante temerárias de se fazer, não a toa que alguns que tentaram implementar vivem pesadelos. E nada indica que DDD só existe em linguagens OO.

Modelo anêmico vai contra OOP, assim como funções sem efeitos colaterais, quebrar o que deveria ser o mesmo objeto em objetos diferentes, só para citar o que viola OO, tem outras coisas que ele manda fazer que é contrário de todo conhecimento adquirido por décadas no processo de desenvolvimento de software.

E só porque o criador de DDD disse certas coisas não quer dizer que sejam corretas. Claro, se você não fizer tudo o que ele diz não pode dizer que seguiu DDD, mas seguir DDD fielmente não é garantia de ter feito um *design* melhor, mais fácil de dar manutenção, mais barato, flexível ou com qualquer característica que tentam vender com ele. No fim **as pessoas envolvidas saberem o que estão fazendo e entender todo o processo sempre será o fator determinante se ficará bom ou não**.

DDD é uma ideia muito boa, mas a forma como mandam implementar é péssima.

Justamente por ser um assunto relativamente novo eu tinha um pouco de receio de dar essa opiniões, e é isso o que as pessoas tem sobre o assunto já que não há muito estudo formal sobre o uso disto, mas cada dia encontro mais programadores de primeira linha com pensamento semelhante ao meu. Quem pensa diferente geralmente é inexperiente (que não é medido em quantidade de anos que trabalha na área), vende consultoria, cursos, ou coisa do tipo.

Por causa destes pontos todos eu discordo da resposta aceita, exceto que DDD é mais sobre o domínio. Até que OOP é algo sobre classes eu discordo :), na verdade por todas as definições confiáveis que já vi isso é errado com certeza.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: -1.O mapa não é o território, não obstante nos usamos mapas para nos orientar. Este post todo parece um "rant" e não responde a questão

Comment: @jean obrigado por confirmar o que eu disse. Eu achei que respondia, coloquei o que é cada um e como as ideias deles são tão diferentes quando se olha como realmente essas disciplinas são sem me ater ao discurso oficial, me desculpe se te desagradou, mas não tem problema, eu gosto de criar conhecimento em cima do conhecimento geral e não específico, por isso não posso seguir a receita de bolo.

Answer (score 2):

Concordo que os objetos do domínio sempre irão ficar devendo com relação à representação do domínio do mundo real e ninguém conseguirá modelar este domínio tão bem assim, mesmo porque no prório mundo real este domínio está sempre mudando e sendo adaptado.

Para mim OOP facilita não porque é uma abstração do domínio mas porque ela traz algumas boas práticas de como estes objetos devem se comunicar entre si.

Falo isso pensando lá no GOF nos padrões criacionais, estruturais e comportamentais.

Como estes objetos são construidos, agrupados e comunicam entre si.

Sobre DDD acho que a idéia é a partir do modelo construir a solução do meu sistema.

Primeiro eu represento as entidades mais próximas possíveis do meu modelo real (aquele processo de negócio que já existe em outro lugar e que alguém já realiza, seja com planilhas do excel sem ter um sistema por exemplo)

Ou seja, eu modelo e depois eu vou adaptar o meu algoritimo que irá resolver um problema.

E não eu crio um algorítimo e depois eu adapto ao meu modelo de negócio.

Acho que é isso.

Bom, isso foi o que eu entendi do que você colocou acima.

Abs

Answer (score 1):

Fica mais fácil ver a diferença se você olhar para DDD como um guia que te orienta na elaboração da solução lógica e OOP como uma forma de implementação dessa solução lógica.

DDD te ajuda a tomar decisões sobre como pensar e entender o que de fato é o problema a ser resolvido e como propor uma solução mais consistente possível. Enquanto que OOP é um paradigma que permite a implementação dos conceitos e práticas sugeridas pelo DDD através de uma linguagem de programação.

Com DDD você aprende mais do que apenas modelar o domínio e criar repositórios, ele aborda decisões arquiteturais importantes para a qualidade e sustentação do sistema. Te ajuda pensar mais cedo possível em coisas que normalmente só pensamos depois de já ter começado. Por exemplo, os nomes que usaremos para as coisas (linguagem ubíqua), o que são entidades e quais características são importantes dela dentro do contexto, o que são objetos de valor, como dividir o sistema em subsistemas (bounded context) para que pessoas diferentes colaborem com o mesmo sistema em paralelo, como esses subsistemas irão se relacionar após serem separados, etc.

Programação Orientada a Objetos vem depois dessas decisões, quando você começar a implementar a solução e precisar de uma linguagem que lhe forneça recursos para trabalhar com conceitos de encapsulamento, polimorfismo, herança, pacotes/namespaces.