# DDD - O que é um domínio complexo?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Costuma-se dizer que DDD (Domain-driven Design) se aplica melhor a *domínios complexos*.

- O que caracteriza um domínio complexo? (por favor seja mais específico do que *"ele possui regras de negócio complexas"*).
- Quais seriam exemplos de domínios complexos?
- Como posso classificar um domínio como complexo (ou seja, apropriado para DDD) ou não?

[Essa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica) não me pareceu suficiente para responder isso. A pergunta atual seria um complemento a ela.

Esta pergunta tem uma versão [em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876263/ddd-what-characterizes-a-complex-domain); vamos ver o que o pessoal responde por lá.

Answer (score 4):

Resposta tipo mestre Yoda(porque provavelmente não vai esgotar o assunto...)

1. Um domínio complexo é basicamente um conjunto de conhecimento com o qual o sistema terá de lidar, granular e disponibilizar, através de seus diversos recursos. Um exemplo simples:

2.1 (domínio simples) um vendedor emite um pedido e envia para a retaguarda(neste cenário, o domínio seria simples, eu não preciso saber muito, não preciso obter muito e não preciso disponibilizar muitas coisas para a retaguarda...)

2.2 (domínio complexo) o vendedor emite o pedido, considerando uma promoção para ALGUNS itens daquele pedido(os outros itens não têm promoção), outros itens possuem bonificação, (ou seja, o cliente compra 1 produto, ganha outro, compra quantidade x de um, ganha outro...); o vendedor, ao fechar o pedido, precisa saber qual o valor final que ele vai receber de comissão. Existe também uma lógica de "conta corrente", na qual, sempre que a margem de venda for melhor, é incrementado um valor na conta corrente do vendedor, sendo esta conta visualizável na retaguarda. Cada vendedor possui um limite máximo para concessão de descontos, o que também é observado para determinados produtos(boa margem de lucro) e clientes(volume de compras, duplicatas em dia, etc.). Com isso, o vendedor novato, vendendo um produto com pouca margem de lucro, a um cliente também novato, configuraria um pior cenário para conceder um desconto. O estoque do produto também é considerado neste cenário. Sendo assim, se o cliente pede 10 unidades de um produto e apenas 3 serão entregues, será necessário gerar um pedido com o saldo, e já informar o cliente previamente sobre o prazo de entrega daquele pedido(um pedido para entrega futura no dispositivo do vendedor e na retaguarda); se o cliente achar que vai demorar muito, ele já quer decidir se deixa o pedido emitido ou não. No momento em que o item for adicionado, a quantidade em estoque deverá estar indicada no mesmo. Na retaguarda é possível verificar se o vendedor visitou o cliente na data estipulada; se o cliente foi visitado, e não foi positivado(não comprou), o vendedor deverá preencher uma justificativa. Se o vendedor não obedeceu o roteiro de visitas por algum motivo, isso ficará claro através dos relatórios da retaguarda.

3. Para determinar se um domínio será complexo, tente responder essas perguntas:

3.1 que nível de granularidade será elicitado nos requisitos?

3.2 de tudo que foi levantado através de requisitos, quanto vou precisar disponibilizar através dos recursos que serão desenvolvidos? (App Mobile, Web API, IoT, etc...)

- Tome coragem e leia o [livro do Evans](http://www.travessa.com.br/DOMAIN_DRIVEN_DESIGN_ATACANDO_AS_COMPLEXIDADES_NO_CORACAO_DO_SOFTWARE/artigo/2f769452-c872-4224-b172-5f83310bb243?pcd=041&gclid=Cj0KEQiA_fy0BRCwiLaQ5-iFgpwBEiQA884sOWCBNAkbaYmNeXp8qZsm7whex82xWbGI6R72udGrCWQaAhE_8P8HAQ) todo. Se um livro pode formar um neuro cirurgião pode formar um programador. Uma coisa é precisar entregar o projeto logo, abstrair algumas coisas superficialmente para poder resolver pontualmente algum problema. Outra é, depois de entregue o projeto, a sensação de que não precisa ler sobre o assunto, porque já entregou a solução. Podemos chamar de auto sabotagem (um dia, aquele conhecimento vai fazer falta). Se não der tempo de fazer uma leitura aprofundada durante o desenvolvimento, faça a leitura assim que puder. No próximo "tiroteio" você terá algumas vantagens.
- Quem estuda padrões de projeto, SCRUM, Kanban, S.O.L.I.D., DDD, TDD e coisas do tipo, ás vezes sofre de "patternite"(termo que conheci com o [Fabio Margarito](http://www.mbcorp.com.br/?p=2217); isso é, quando o programador quer utilizar padrão em tudo). O fato de sermos capacitados não nos impede de sermos pragmáticos, sempre que possível.
- O que precisamos entender no DDD é: nossa capacidade de codificação é um acessório para a solução que será proposta. Conforme o Evans diz no livro, a cada novo domínio, aquele assunto para a fazer parte de nós. É essa capacidade de envolver-se com as questões/dores do cliente que parece que o pessoal não tá muito a fim, mas esse é o papo. Para resolver o problema do cliente, eu uso o sotaque dele, o linguajar dele, e modelo o código/solução de acordo com o problema que pelo cliente foi transmitido(mesmo que tenhamos apenas um guardanapo de papel)

Boa sorte!