# Como deve ser a comunicação entre Model e View usando MVC?

Tags: java, android, arquitetura-de-software

Estou tentando implementar alguns pequenos projetos utilizando o padrão MVC: Dentro da estrutura do projeto, criei os seguintes pacotes:

- View : Telas de interação com o usuário.
- Controller: Tenho uma classe com métodos referente as requisições do usuário, salvar, alterar, deletar, listar.
- Modal: Classe que implementa o método Serializable.

Como a aplicação é com integração a banco de dados local SQLite, possui mais dois pacotes:

- DataModal: Contem o modelo de dados do projeto.
- DataSource: Contem a fonte de dados, nas mesma é criado o banco, nesta mesma classe possuo o método de persistência de dados. Salvar, deletar e listar.

Pelo que percebi, o controller não se comunica com o DataSource, tal comunicação se da entre DataSource e Model. Os métodos de inserção, atualização, remoção e para listar os registros, devem ser criados em uma classe separada no Modal? Como se daria a comunicação entre o mesmo e o Controller, e de que forma o Modal devolver as informações para a View: passando diretamente, ou deve passar para o Controller e o Controller fornecer essa informação a View?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá.

*Os métodos de inserção, atualização, remoção e para listar os registros, devem ser criados em uma classe separada no Modal?*

Isso vai depender da sua arquitetura, você pode "desacoplar" essa parte criando uma parte do sistema que faça o `CRUD` e forneça para o Model os dados e então ele passa esses dados para os `Controllers`. Veja [DDD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19548/11404).

*Como se daria a comunicação entre o mesmo e o Controller, e de que forma o Modal devolver as informações para a View: passando diretamente, ou deve passar para o Controller e o Controller fornecer essa informação a View?*

- Como se daria a comunicação entre o mesmo e o Controller

  Para usar um `Model` no `Controller` , você pode instanciar a classe do `Model` e acessar seus respectivos métodos.
- e de que forma o Modal devolver as informações para a View

Quando você criar um `Controller` você associa uma `View` à ele, e assim você tem acesso aos elementos dela, podendo controlar-los, o `Model` não tem conhecimento das `Views` é o `Controller` quem faz essa "ponte" entre eles.

Sugiro que dê uma lida neste post [MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55490/11404) e este artigo [MVC](http://tableless.com.br/mvc-afinal-e-o-que/)

Comment: JcSaint - Obrigado pelo auxilio, a partir de sua explicação, post e artigo, vou buscar entender mais a fundo sobre esse conceito e implementar aqui. Grande abraço, tudo de bom.

Comment: @RodrigoTiburski disponha... :)

Answer (score 0):

*"Pelo que percebi, o controller não se comunica com o DataSource"*

A classe de controle, que é nada mais e nada menos que a activity, tem sim que se comunicar com a classe que insere/delete/modifica os dados.

Pra clarificar meu pensamento:
View = XML;
Controller = Activity;
Model = Entidades (banco);

Seu banco terá uma classe que o crie. Voce pode criar uma outra classe que gerencie o banco pra facilitar a inserção dos dados.
A activity joga os dados nesse classe gerenciadora que recebe da view (na verdade os dados já vão estar na própria activity, já que o xml é uma "ilusão")

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, simples, porém extremamente objetiva, e de grande auxílio para seguir os estudos. Grande abraço, tudo de bom a você.

Comment: "A classe de controle [...] tem sim que se comunicar com a classe que insere/delete/modifica os dados." Nao, nao tem, e nao deve. Controller devem ser as classes mais BURRAS da aplicacao. Elas nao tomam decisao e nem conhecimento da infraestrutura da aplicacao. Elas servem apenas, e somente apenas, para controlar rotas. Quem toma decisao sao Dominios, e esses sim recebem infra de persistencia via injecao.

Comment: Então...eu acho que é isso mesmo que eu disse. O controle só chama o domínio e ele por sua vez faz as operações.