# Organização de código PHP

Tags: php, organização-de-projeto, padrão-dao

Estou trabalhando em um projeto PHP em que várias tabelas se relacionam com várias tabelas, então como devo organizar os controllers e DAOs,

**dividir os arquivos por tabela** - funcionarios, vendas, clientes, ...

ou

**agrupar pelas ações** - funcionarios + vendas (ações do funcionario mais as ações do funcionario relacionadas as vendas), clientes + funcionarios (ações do cliente mais ações do cliente relacionadas aos funcionários), ...

Se eu agrupar por tabela terei um código mais organizado e mais reaproveitamento de código, porém agrupar por ações torna mais rápido a medida que eu não precisarei transferir dados entre controllers e não precisarei chamar mais de um DAO.

Essa diferença de performance é significativa, considerando que são poucos acessos a aplicação?

Quando saber quando um é mais vantajoso que outro?

Comment: Olha, o fato é que existem diversas formas de organizar seu código, além até das duas que citou... Recomendo que veja além da parte técnica, as pessoas que irão trabalhar no projeto no futuro. Seja lá qual for a forma que escolher, escolha pela facilidade de escalar e dar manutenção no fonte. Infelizmente não fazem tanto isso quanto deveriam, e acho louvável sua pergunta. PArabéns!

Comment: @DiegoSantos poderia montar uma resposta com outras formas de organização de projeto?

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta como pediu. Porém, com minha experiência. Não é uma verdade universal, mas acredito que pode lhe ser útil. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como sabemos, existem diversas formas de organização de scripts num projeto. 
Todas claro possuem pontos positivos e outros negativos perante a necessidade.

Vou citar abaixo formas pelas quais já vi e o que acho de cada uma, pela MINHA experiência.

> Organizar por tabelas:

É uma forma direta e de fácil compreensão. Porém, isso para quem já conhece o contexto da aplicação. Se for algo que o desenv realmente não conheça ele vai se perder na base de dados e no fonte.

> Organizar por domínio:

Hoje trabalho muito com MVC e com DDD.
Confesso que me adapto melhor com DDD. Faz mais sentido para mim organizar o sistema em domínios.

Porém, as vezes acrescentamos complexidade demais a estrutura do projeto, se não seguirmos corretamente este padrão.
**Recomendo este.**

> Organizar por camadas

Sinceramente, já vi programadores se perderem mais nesse modelo do que nos outros.
É muito fácil sistemas nascerem com este padrão mas com o tempo ficarem bagunçados, somente pelo fato de que cada programador entende uma funcionalidade em uma camada distinta. Desta forma, em pouco tempo, o sistema se torna um "monstro".

Com relação ao DAO.
Existe também outro padrão de acesso que é o de repositórios.
Ao invés de criar objetos que acessam dados diretamente, cria-se repositórios que realizam consultas.
Neste caso, você pode criar repositórios aderentes à regra de negócio e não abstrações dos modelos criados.

**Exemplo:** Quando estamos criando um relatório fazemos diversas consultas no mesmo contexto.
É fácil prever que o melhor a se fazer é trazer todas as informações de uma vez e destrinchar os dados em tela. Correto?
Desta forma, poderia ser criado um repositório que atenda esta necessidade deste relatório, por exemplo, utilizando os modelos como padrões, parse, apenas.

> **Importante:**

Isto não é uma resposta bala de prata!
Existem diversos padrões por aí e independente de qual escolha, pense no ciclo de vida do software que está produzindo. 
Você não será o único a trabalhar nele. 
Conhecendo a empresa que está trabalhando, e possível prever razoavelmente o perfil das pessoas que irão estar no seu lugar no futuro. Desta forma, é possível escolher um padrão que seja de fácil manutenção e de fácil escalabilidade.

Comment: Poderia explicar a organixação por domínio?

Comment: É a organização DDD. Drive Domain design. Veja explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica

Answer (score 1):

Para tentar organizar o projeto da melhor forma possível (mais reaproveitamento de código de forma a interferir o mínimo possível na performance) divide o projeto em 4 partes:

1. **View** (interface, dividida por açẽos)
2. **Router** (cuida da parte de redirecionamento, dividida por ações)
3. **Controller** (Regras de negócio, dividida por tabela)
4. **DAO** (Acesso ao banco e execusão dos SQL, dividida por tabela)

A view envia para o router uma solicitação (por exemplo, cadastro de usuário)

O router guarda os dados passados via `$_GET` ou `$_POST` e chama as funções do controller

As funções do controller valida e aplica as regras de negócio e chama as funções do DAO

As funções do DAO apenas executam os SQL e podem retornar 3 valores:

1. `false`: caso a execução fracasse
2. `true`: caso o `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `DELETE` tenha êxito
3. `Array`: caso o `SELECT` tenha êxito

O controller verifica o resultado do DAO, se o DAO fracasse, cria uma sessão com menssagem de erro e retorna `false` ao router ou, caso o DAO tenha êxito, retorna `true` ou um `Array`

Router verifica o retorno e redireciona ou para uma página de erro (`erro.php`, por exemplo) ou para a página correta

Esse modelo, tem como principal vantagem a reutilização das regras de negócio e dos scripts SQl, tendo apenas repetições de código nos redirecionamentos (`header("location: ...")`), assim também não é necessário passar dados entre controllers