# Varios CRUD em um mesmo projeto PHP

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, design-pattern, crud, organização-de-projeto

Olá, tenho uma duvida sobre estruturação de um projeto, no caso é em PHP.

Digamos que eu tenha 3 CRUD para fazer, um seria de produtos, outro de clientes e o ultimo de pedidos.

Nesse caso, eu teria que estrutura o projeto mais ou menos assim:

*Aplicação:

- Cliente:CREATE
         READ
         UPDATE
         DELETE
- Produto:CREATE
         READ
         UPDATE
         DELETE
- Pedido:CREATE
        READ
        UPDATE
        DELETE

Existe alguma outra forma, que trataria o uso de menos arquivos ou um tipo de estruturação mais flexível, sem dotar o uso de framework?

Comment: Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282997/organiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-php) relacionada a isso. Sugiro que pesquise também sobre os padrões DAO, MVC e DDD. Mesmo que não use um framework pode se basear na estrutura dos mesmos

Comment: Sim, o uso de MVC será adepto a mim. Que eu queria saber se existe alguma outra forma, além do MVC. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que vocÊ realmente não queira aplicar um padrão de projeto, ou um framework elaborado, você pode usar um 'mini framework' (sem ironia, não consegui pensar em outro nome kk) pra isso:

Segue um exemplo de forma rudimentar, mas da pra tomar uma base pra você aplicar em seu projeto:

**1 - Formulários**

**Create**

Para criação, teremos que informar uma tabela, e os campos que haverão nesta tabela:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="clientes">
  <input type="text" name="nome">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Salvar usuário">
</form>
```

**Update**

Para atualizar vamos informar qual a tabela, qual o registro será atualizado, e os dados que atualizarão:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="clientes">
  <input type="hidden" name="update" value="cliente 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="field" value="nome">
  <input type="text" name="nome">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Editar usuário">
</form>
```

**Delete**

Para deletar, precisamos apenas informar a tabela, e o registro que sera deletado:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="clientes">
  <input type="text" name="nome" value="cliente 1">
  <input type="submit" value="Excluir usuário">
</form>
```

**Read**

Para ler os dados, incluiremos um arquivo com a função, e como parâmetro da função, informamos a tabela que será consultada:

```
<?php
include 'read.php';
echo read('clientes');
```

**2 - Lógica**

Agora vamos a parte lógica, são arquivos simples que vão tratar os dados submetidos via `$_POST` para construir as queries:

**Create**
Na criação, vamos recebero post, separar o valor 'form', que será o nome da tabela, e rodar dois loops, um informará pelo nome do campo do formulário o campo do banco, e outro loop informará os respectivos valores:

```
<?php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $_POST['form'] . ' (';
unset($_POST['form']);
$c = 1;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(count($_POST) > $c){
    $sql .= $key.',';
  }else{
    $sql .= $key;
  }
  $c+=1;
}
$sql .= ') VALUES (';

$c = 1;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(count($_POST) > $c){
    $sql .= '"'.$value.'"'.',';
  }else{
    $sql .= '"'.$value.'"';
  }
  $c+=1;
}
$sql .= ')';
echo $sql;
```

**Update**

Para atualizar os dados, nós recebemos a tabela (form), o campo que será comparado e o valor que deve ser encontrado para atualizar, na sequencia é aberto um loop para adicionar os campos e seus respectivos valores:

```
<?php
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $_POST['form'] . ' SET ';
unset($_POST['form']);
$update =$_POST['update'];
unset($_POST['update']);
$field = $_POST['field'];
unset($_POST['field']);
$c = 1;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(count($_POST) > $c){
    $sql .= $key.'="'.$value.'",';
  }else{
    $sql .= $key.'="'.$value.'"';
  }
  $c+=1;
}
$sql .= ' WHERE ' .$field . ' = "' . $update . '"';

echo $sql;
```

**Delete**

Para deletar o valor, também vamos receber a tabela (form), vamos remover o form da array $_POST, e na sequência usaremos a chave do campo, e o valor para informar qual é o valor a ser deletado:

```
<?php
$sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $_POST['form'] . ' WHERE ';
unset($_POST['form']);

$sql .= key($_POST) . ' = "' . $_POST[key($_POST)] . '"';

echo $sql;
```

**Read**

Para ler os dados, teremos um função que vai receber como parâmetro o nome da tabela que deve ser consultada:

```
<?php
function read($tabela){
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tabela;
  return $sql;
}
```

**Explicando:**

Como disse que não queria um framework, essa é uma forma bem rudimentar de ter menos arquivos, esse é um padrão que você pode usar para submeter vários formulários, usando uma base lógica, que vai tratar pelos 'names' do campos de seu formulário e construir suas queries com base neles, se manter esse padrão simples podes trabalhar até com formulários grandes.

Porém, não é uma boa prática, pois teria de tratar muitas vezes os dados e trabalhar com aliases (uma delas é mudar os nomes dos campos após a submissão pro usuário não saber os verdadeiros nomes dos campos no seu banco).

Existem padrões mais organizados, onde você pode receber cada formulário em uma classe separada, e unificar as funções de interação com banco.

**Finalizando**

Um dos padrões mais utilizados e relativamente fácil de se aplicar, é o padrão [MVC](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308), onde você terá um **C**ontrolador responsável por saber o que precisa ser chamado, **M**odels para trabalhar com a parte lógica de tratamento e submissão, e uma **V**iew para devolver as respostas.

Um ótimo exemplo de **CRUD** que utiliza o **MVC**, é a forma que trabalham as rotas do [**Laravel**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6), que chamam um [**controlador**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers) e esse controlador informa o **model** o que ela deve fazer ou trazem alguma [**View**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views) como resposta.

Como você disse na pergunta que não queria um framework, não vou aprofundar nesse padrão, fica uma explicação de um modo alternativo de se ter menos arquivos para trabalhar com vários CRUD's, porém pessoalmente, acredito que uso do padrão de algum framework facilita e agiliza muito o trabalho.

Comment: Isso, eu estou ciente do uso de um padrão MVC. Que eu preciso fazer exatamente assim, na verdade basicamente PHP puro. Mas vou seguir suas dicas, irão me ajuda bastante! Valeu :D