# O que é uma classe de domínio?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes

O que é uma classe de domínio? Por que "de domínio"? Há métodos que ela não deve ter (que não é da sua função ter determinado tipo de método)? Ela admite quais tipos de métodos?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 5):

Há controvérsias.

Geralmente aceita-se que é uma classe que representa entidades de negócios. É comum que sejam classes que servem de agregado de outras classes que também são domínios ou mecanismos (por exemplo o que faz a persistência de dados).

Alguns dizem que deve ser uma classe anêmica, ou seja, não tem métodos, ou tem só os ligados com os campos. Outros admitem que podem ter outros tipos de métodos ligados ao domínio, ou seja, à regra de negócio. Não entra métodos ligados ao software em si.

Há quem diga que é qualquer classe. Mesmo os mecanismos tem seu próprio domínio.

Há quem diga que o termo nem é correto e só existe o modelo de domínio e não classe, até porque o domínio é composto de várias classes.

Enfim, é algo conceitual no sentido negativo. É um termo que não casa com o que as pessoas usam de fato, é confuso, não ajuda dar melhor entendimento e eu prefiro ignorar na forma que costuma ser apresentado. Se criarem coisas mais bem definidas para a mesma ideia talvez se torne interessante.

Claro, quem aprende de um jeito e gosta vai dizer que aquilo é o certo e que é ótimo. Bom pra essa pessoa. Veja se é bom pra você. Pra mim não é.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que é domínio?

Comment: Estou lendo um livro de EF e lá ele fala "domain class" e no exemplo que está dando são duas classes (Destino e Hospedagem) criadas no projeto Model.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(software_engineering). Então, cada fonte trata de um jeito.

Comment: É a mesma coisa? [O que realmente é DDD e quando ele se aplica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica)

Comment: @Marconi acho relacionado, mesma coisa acho que não.

Answer (score 0):

Classes de domínio são usados para criar os vários elementos no domínio e relações de domínio são os links entre os elementos. Eles são a representação de tempo de design, os elementos e links que serão instanciados pelos usuários da linguagem de design específicas ao criar seus modelos.

As suas propriedades são:

> Modificador de acesso:    O nível de acesso da classe de domínio (public ou internal).
>   Atributos personalizados:   Usado para adicionar atributos para a classe de código de origem que é gerada a partir dessa classe de domínio.
>   Gera dois derivados Se True, uma classe base e uma classe parcial (para oferecer suporte a personalização por meio de substituições) será gerada. Para obter mais informações, consulte substituindo e estendendo as Classes geradas por.
>   Tem um construtor personalizado:    Se True, um construtor personalizado será fornecido no código-fonte. Para obter mais informações, consulte substituindo e estendendo as Classes geradas por.
>
> Modificador de Herança:   Descreve o tipo de herança da classe de código fonte que é gerada a partir da classe de domínio (none, abstract ou sealed). none
>   Classe Base Se essa classe de domínio é derivada, o nome da classe base.
>   Nome:   O nome dessa classe de domínio. 
>   espaço de nome: O namespace dessa classe de domínio.    Namespace atual
>   Observações Notas informais associadas essa classe de domínio.  <>>
>   Descrição   A descrição é usada para documentar a interface do usuário do designer gerado.
>   Nome de Exibição:   O nome que será exibido no designer gerado para esta classe de domínio.
>   Palavra-chave de ajuda: A palavra-chave opcional que é usada para indexar a Ajuda de F1 para essa classe de domínio.

FONTE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb126503.aspx
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/modeling/understanding-models-classes-and-relationships