# O que devo saber para poder utilizar o React como minha biblioteca de front-end?

Tags: react

Minha dúvida se divide em três pontos:

- Existem tipos de aplicações onde o uso do React é muito eficiente? Ou onde ele seria dispensável ou não recomendado? Quais seriam?
- Quais são as outras tecnologias (bibliotecas, frameworks, conceitos, banco de dados, back-end) que costumam ser aprendidas/utilizadas para usar em conjunto com o React?
- Como funciona essa interação do React com Back-end e Banco de dados?

Comment: Eu diria que a pergunta é muito ampla. Além de 3 perguntas, que nem sempre é um problema, tem coisa para falar aí mais do que um capítulo de livro. Fora que falta informações. Ser melhor em comparação com o que? Qual o contexto? melhor para quem? Começa resvalar em não claro e até baseado em opinião. Pede uma lista de listas de coisas.

Comment: Acho que as vezes nos prendemos muito as regras de perguntas e deixamos de prover um conteúdo proveitoso, ainda que seja baseado opinião. Mas entendo que uma exceção pode abrir precedentes. Vou remover a pergunta

Comment: Antes, conhecem algum forum no qual eu possa fazer esse tipo de pergunta?

Comment: Então a solução é abandonar as regras e deixar todo mundo fazer o que bem quiser?

Comment: Não. Eu concordo com a sua observação, acho que você está correto e o site também. Só que não anula o fato de pensar que algumas vezes deixamos de ter um conteúdo útil e relevante no site por conta disso.

Comment: Se concordasse não teria feito a pergunta e colocado uma recompensa para impedir o fechamento. Falar que concorda e fazer o oposto é pior do que discordar. Tentar mudar algo é uma coisa, passar por cima do foi estabelecido é outra. O que está dizendo é no mínimo inócuo.

Comment: Não estava claro pra mim se era fora do escopo. Já vi perguntas bem no limite dessa interpretação que foram respondidas sem nenhum problema. Quanto a recompensa realmente não sabia que impedia de fechar a pergunta. Não é minha intenção discutir, só expus minha opinião. Respeito sua interpretação e aprendi com a situação. Abraço!

Comment: Não é fora de escopo. O fato de passar outras não indica que é aceito. DÊ uma exemplo de pergunta que acha que é na mesma linha que esta.

Comment: Para mim um exemplo era esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica, mas olhando com mais cuidado já vejo a diferença.

Comment: Só digo uma coisa: todo e qualquer framework surge para resolver um problema. Entenda o problema e entenderá o framework. Se não existir o problema, o framework nem deveria existir.

Comment: Com um bocado de sorte puderá ser possivél responder á segunda pergunta, caso haja alguma fonte dum estudo das técnologias que costumam ser usadas com React. Mas nenhuma das outras perguntas faz sentido. `Existem tipos de aplicações onde o uso do React é muito eficiente? Ou onde ele seria dispensável ou não recomendado? Quais seriam?` - Voce pode virtualmente usar qualquer framework em qualquer situacao, especialmente quando está a falar de frameworks UI como o React. `Como funciona essa interação do React com Back-end e Banco de dados?` - Da mesma forma que funciona com outra framework

Comment: @BrunoCosta nem é mais minha intenção que respondam, já estou estudando tudo por conta própria e iniciei um curso online de React, em breve talvez eu mesmo responda. Mas quanto aos seus questionamentos, acho que se foi perguntado é por que essas dúvidas que parecem obvias pra quem domina alguns assuntos não eram obvias para mim. Estou numa comunidade onde existem talvez os melhores especialistas brasileiros e portugueses, e ao mesmo tempo os mais iniciantes. Então sempre vale a pena consultar os mais experientes, para pegar uma direção e o caminho de aprendizado ser mais curto.

Comment: Ainda que seja pra responderem que as dúvidas não fazem sentido e o por quê não fazem. Você falando isso já ajuda e esclarece algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder porque acredito que essas perguntas muito amplas podem ser respondidas com uma introdução as suas partes e, se for necessário, o autor pode buscar por mais informações dessas partes em outras perguntas

> Existem tipos de aplicações onde o uso do React é muito eficiente? Ou onde ele seria dispensável ou não recomendado? Quais seriam?

A pergunta que você deve fazer primeiro é **eu preciso usar uma biblioteca/framework?**, algo que é muito simples, por exemplo, uma página estática que no máximo envia um email de contato ou uma aplicação que tu fez pra uso próprio apenas para cadastrar lembretes, não é algo que necessite de mais um dependência

Agora, partindo do princípio que sua aplicação merece uma biblioteca ou framework, o React tem algo que o torna perfeito para determinada situação? Não, em geral qualquer uma que você usar terá um bom resultado (pelo menos as principais: React, Vue e Angular)

Apesar da biblioteca em si não ter algo que a torne especial, as pessoas que vão a utilizar podem preferir uma ou outra, por exemplo:

- Alguém que já conhece a linguagem, mas não muito as ferramentas e estrutura, e está entrando no mundo das bibliotecas/frameworks javascript, pode preferir o Angular por ser um framework, é mais completo, já vem com uma estrutura pronta pra usar, o CLI (Interface de Linha de Comando) que ajuda bastante na criação dos arquivos
- Um time em que uma parte usa um e não gosta de outro, o Vue é o meio termo, se souber um deles, você consegue usar tranquilamente os outros mas, entre os três, uma mudança de React ou Angular para Vue é mais sucinta do que De Angular para React e vice-versa
- Dentre os três o React tem sido o preferido (pelo que eu vejo, apenas uma percepção sem método científico, posso estar enganado) para ser usado com Three para criar interfaces 3D, não significa que não seja possível com os outros

> Quais são as outras tecnologias (bibliotecas, frameworks, conceitos, banco de dados, back-end) que costumam ser aprendidas/utilizadas para usar em conjunto com o React?
>
> Como funciona essa interação do React com Back-end e Banco de dados?

Vou juntar essas perguntas porque parte da resposta seria pra ambas

Em geral você não vai usar nenhuma biblioteca ou framework para se conectar com um banco de dados, até pode usar o WebSQL, LocalStorage ou SessionStorage, porém é menos de 1% dos casos, mas provavelmente vai querer guardar os dados do usuário logado em algum dos dois últimos e isso é igual ao javascript puro

O que você vai fazer é se comunicar com seu back (que pode ser em qualquer linguagem) e ele com seu banco (qualquer um, SQL ou NoSQL), para isso você irá realizar chamadas HTTP assíncronas, essa é a utilidade do Axios, onde você tem métodos como `Aios.get` e `Axios.post` que retornam uma Promise que pode ser usada com `Promise.then` e `Promise.catch` ou `async` e `await`. Essa é apenas uma biblioteca, tem outras que podem ser usadas

Se seu back for um BaaS, você deve usar a biblioteca que ele oferece para o react, por exemplo, o Firebase possui o ReactFire

Além disso, você deve ter pelo menos uma noção de algumas outras coisas:

- Web Component
- JSX
- TypeScript
- Webpack
- Babel
- [Alguma biblioteca de roteamento](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html)

Talvez não irá a usar tudo ai em cima num único projeto, mas é interessante ter uma boa base

Comment: Era exatamente uma resposta assim que eu buscava. As vezes queremos aprender algo que percebemos que tem procura por profissionais, mas antes de aprender é sempre bom entender o que é aquilo num contexto mais amplo (coisa que geralmente não encontramos em tutoriais na internet), o que você conseguiu passar numa resposta concisa e objetiva, mesmo numa pergunta que não teve essas mesmas características. Você entendeu bem o que eu pretendia.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo pela minha experiência com o React, é interessante utilizar mais se você pretende fazer um front-end de um sistema web com um bom desempenho e se é preciso manipular dados pela página.

Se você pretende fazer mais um projeto com uma página meio que estática e sem muita manipulação de dados e simples o Jquery pode ser muito útil para você!

Para se comunicar com o back-end é através protocolo http, se utiliza muito o axios que ajuda a manipular as chamadas http! Bem interessante e indico para quem está começando!

Comment: O que é o Axios?

Answer (score 0):

1 - O react pode ser usado em qualquer tipo de aplicação, claro que se for para uma página estática, por exemplo, não há muita necessidade a utilização dele, você pode usar o jquery para isso. Eu aconselho a utilização de ferramentas como o react, vue e angular para aplicações um pouco maiores onde você possui muitas páginas e componentes.

2 e 3- Nossa, ai depende muito. Você pode usar ruby on rails, laravel entre outros frameworks de backend. E banco você pode usar qualquer um também, aqui na empresa onde trabalho a gente costuma dividir os projetos. Então todo nosso backend é uma api (rails + graphQL pegando dados do MySQL)  e temos o frontend se comunicando com essa api pegando os dados através do axios ou apollo. Mas pode fazer tudo em um só projeto mesmo. 
Você pode conferir algumas coisas relacionadas nesses links abaixo:

react + laravel: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app-with-laravel-backend-part-2-react--cms-29443

Rails + graphQL + react https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXsGSADDlNw

Comment: Além disso, pelo que tenho pesquisado, ele é bom pela facilidade de reutilização de componentes, facilidade de manutenção, testabilidade e performance. Imagino que sua utilização em um site simples, com pouca ou nenhuma interatividade não consiga tirar proveito desses benefícios, tornando sua utilização desnecessária. Quanto as bibliotecas, conceitos e etc, acho que não dá pra responder mesmo, foi uma pergunta de alguém que não tinha base alguma. E quanto a interação com o back-end, entendo agora que é por API, não importando a linguagem ou o banco de dados.